# What level of indirection to use in structs?

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I want to create a simple structure that holds an identifier of type `int` and a value of any kind. Should I use

```
struct {
    int key;
    void *value;
}
```

or

```
struct {
    int key;
    void **value;
}
```

or something else?

Comment: @Mihran: C (look at the tags ;))

Comment: @user282636 :) I thought that maybe you forgot c++ tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the first since a `void*` can point to anything. There doesn't appear to be any need for a double indirection in your case.

You should also keep in mind that there is another way, one that involves having a variable size payload within the structure rather than a fixed `void*`. It's useful in the case where the structures themselves are allocated (such as in a linked list) so you can make them variable sized by adjusting the argument to `malloc`.

In that case, you can avoid pointers in the structure altogether. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736307/multipurpose-linked-list-implementation-in-pure-c/736392#736392) for more details. I'm not suggesting that it's necessary (or even a good idea) for this particular case, just providing it as another possibility. I suspect your option 1 will be more than enough, or supplying a union within the structure if you don't want any pointer in there.

Comment: So far, I always stored a pointer as my value. Since all pointers are equal in size on a given system (true?), I don't really have to keep track of the size.

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to use a combination of union and struct:

```
struct my_struct {
        int key;
        union {
                int a_int;
                float a_float;
                char a_char;
                /* Other types You may need */
        } value;
}
```

The pointer only points to a variable, it doesn't hold its value. You have to store actual variable somewhere else.

Comment: No, I'm storing complex, variable-size data in my structure.

Comment: Use void*. Well, You can always cast it to void**.