# Design of a linked list implementation in C

Tags: c, data-structures

At the moment I am working on creating a small library for common data structures in C. This is mainly for learning purposes, but I do plan to use this library in other projects to see how well it works and where the problems are. So far I'm content with my hash and binary tree implementation, but I cannot decide on the design of the linked list.

All the data structures implemented so far work with `void` pointers and take no responsibility for creating or destroying data, i.e. they only reference the data. One design goal is to keep them as generic as possible to increase the reuseability.

Regarding the linked list, I've found three approaches so far:

1. **Dedicated list head**: the list features a dedicated list head which is used as an abstract data type.
2. **Nodes only**: like the example above, except that all functions operate on a `list_node`. Used in [GLib](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/glist.c).
3. **In payload**: add a `list_node` structure to the payload data and calculate the offset to the payload with a macro. See [lists in the linux kernel](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)
4. *EDIT* **Generate typed lists with macros**: use macros to create type-specific versions of the list structures and functions.

   *Example for 1 and 2:*

```
/* list.h */
typedef struct list_t list;

typedef int (*comparator)(const void* a, const void* b);

list* list_new          (comparator c);
void  list_delete       (list* l);
void  list_insert_after (list* l, uint32_t index, void* data);
void  list_remove       (list* l, void* data);
uint32_t list_size      (list* l);
/* other functions operating on lists */

/* list.c */
#include "list.h"

typedef struct list_node_t {
  struct list_node_t* next;
  struct list_node_t* prev;
  void* data;
} list_node;

struct list_t {
  list_node* begin;
  list_node* end;
  uint32_t   size;
  comparator cmp;
}
```

**Now to the question:** which of these approaches is the most versatile? Are there any other approaches?

Comment: It's probably better to use `size_t` for `index`, `size`, etc, rather than `uint32_t`.

Comment: you've got comparators in there, are you trying to implement a priority queue? A basic linked list doesn't need comparators and heaps are a better structure for handling pqueues

Comment: You might want to take a look at sys/queue.h for implementations too.

Comment: @tobyodavies the comparator is needed for `list_remove` and `list_insert_after` in the example above, because those two functions would find the element in question by comparing it to whatever is there where the data pointer points to.

Comment: @Dario - Perhaps those two functions should take a comparator argument, rather than making it an inherent part of the list.

Comment: Also, don't use macros to make type-specific functions. That sounds like a thoroughly clunky way to imitate templates in C. I much prefer option 3, but `offsetof` isn't necessary if you're willing to always put the list member at the head and write all of your functions as taking `void *` or as macros. (Macros would allow you to make a `new` function that does heap allocation but is generic to the actual list type.)

Comment: @Chris that does indeed make more sense. 
Well macros are used in sglib mentioned in an answer, so I thought I'd add them to the list.
Btw, a generic `new` is possible without macros: [OOC](www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf)

Comment: @PaulR could you elaborate that please?

Comment: @Dario - I've read OOC (I'm sort of working on a project based on it) and it seems a bit heavyweight for what you want based on your descriptions. I was thinking more of "generic for linked list types" rather than "generic for all your containers" (though if you manage to go all the way, I applaud you). `#define list_new(name, next, prev) do { name = malloc(sizeof *name); ((node *)name)->next = next; ((node *)name)->prev == prev; } while(0)`

Comment: @Dario - Sorry for the half comment. My finger slipped and the iPhone is touchy. Regarding `size_t`, it is a type defined in the standard to be the type large enough to hold the size of the largest possible object (more accurately, the type returned by `sizeof`). It is used for string and array sizes, and is the type you pass to `malloc` and friends. It isn't guaranteed to be the same size as `intptr_t`, though it often is, but it is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any size you need, which `int32_t` would not be on, say, a 64-bit system.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Chris: You could have a funny implementation in which the maximum size of an object is, say, 32 bits, but the available address space and memory is larger, so that `(u)intptr_t` is larger and a linked list *could* have more elements than `SIZE_MAX`. I think that's part of the rationale why each C++ container has its own independent `size_type`, and the same would apply to a C container library. In practice, segmented 32/64 bit architecture? Doubt it, so we're talking legacy systems.

Comment: @Steve - This is true. I asked a question about whether `size_t` is guaranteed to be the same size as `uintptr_t` and got that very answer a while ago. I do however doubt the reintroduction of segmented architectures in the near future, though I suppose such an architecture would require `uintptr_t` for the size of a linked list (since links could concievably be in many segments). Hmm...

Comment: @Chris: it's probably not a major restriction if your linked list can only report sizes up to `SIZE_MAX` - clients should count themselves lucky that getting the size is O(1) ;-). Using `uintptr_t` would also be a restriction, since it's an optional type, so if we're trying to be completely portable we have a tricky issue. C implementations are not required to have a type capable of representing the number of objects existing in the program.

Comment: @Steve - `#ifdef UINTPTR_MAX` / `typedef uintptr_t list_size_type;` / `#else` / `typedef uintmax_t list_sizetype;` / `#endif` ought never to have problems. Of course, `size_t` ought never to have problems either realistically.

Comment: @Chris: Relying on the list member being at the head of the containing structure means that you can't have an object be a part of two or more lists.

Comment: Because this question needs more comments, I should also add that I think the `_t` suffix is reserved by the standard for future expansion, and is probably not safe to use for user-defined typenames.

Comment: @caf - True. I think it's a cleaner interface and implementation though.

Comment: @Chris: Or you could use `uintmax_t` always, and just take the risk that this will be a waste of space on some implementation with a bigger integer type than `uintptr_t`. "Ought never to have problems" provided that you check on insert that you aren't wrapping the size around, which is annoying considering that we don't believe it ever can on any modern implementation.

Comment: @Steve - The space would be doubly wasted due to probable alignment issues, unless the size were the first element. I know it's probably insignificant but it feels kind of sad. Also it might make math involving list sizes less efficient if, say, `intmax_t` is larger than the register. (As long as we're arguing for historics the PDP-11 version of Unix had a 32-bit `long` that required multiple instructions to work with. Likewise 32-bit Windows had 64-bit `long long`, and I suspect when people start looking to go bigger than 64 bits we'll see that happen again with `long long`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Multipurpose' linked list implementation in pure C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736307/multipurpose-linked-list-implementation-in-pure-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the second approach, i.e. nodes only.

It has the advantage of being extremely simple, since the results of most list operations (split, push, pop, sublist, ...) are themselves lists.

Also note that you're lacking important list operations, mainly `push()` and `pop()`. You should make use of the fact that lists allow insertion in O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The interface given in the example is by no means complete, it is just supposed to illustrate the point.

Comment: I'd actually prefer a mix of 1 and 2 - 2 for when nodes are enough, but 1 for situations when the extra info that can be stored in a lis head (i.e. `end`, `size`, etc.) can cause significant speedups.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't necessarily have to use void * pointers.
You can use macro pasting tricks to generate types/function(by appending type name to types and functions) for generic type safe data structures.

ex.: http://sglib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Certainly an interesting approach, do you know of any projects that use sglib?