# Standard implementation of a linked list in C

Tags: c

Is there something like a standard implementation of a list in C? I am not finding anything in the standard libraries.

Do you have a recommendation of a c library that implements standard data types like list, map etc.? I am searching for a slim one-file solution.

Comment: Linux's `list.h` - I'd link it but I'm on my phone, you can find it easily if you Google "linux list.h".

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for a library that offers all standard data types (lists and maps are only two examples of data structures, but why would it contain these and not queues, heaps, ...?), and you hope it will be slim and fit in one file? Weird things exists out there, and you may even find a one-file library, but it will be one huge file and the library won't be better for it.

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/116650/is-there-any-boost-equivalent-library-for-c

Answer (score 5):

Many unix systems have a few different implementations in [sys/queue.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/queue.3.html)

Answer (score 4):

The [GLib library](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) contains plenty of data structures including [linked lists](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html) and, for maps, [hash tables](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Hash-Tables.html) and [balanced binary trees](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html). I'm unsure whether you will consider it “slim”, though.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Linux Kernel Linked List](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) in [this answer to a question about multi-purpose linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961444/10396)