# What is the difference between "typename" and "class" template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, keyword

For templates I have seen both declarations:

```
template < typename T >
template < class T >
```

What's the difference?

And what exactly do those keywords mean in the following example (taken from the German Wikipedia article about templates)?

```
template < template < typename, typename > class Container, typename Type >
class Example
{
     Container< Type, std::allocator < Type > > baz;
};
```

Answer (score 607, accepted):

`typename` and `class` are interchangeable in the basic case of specifying a template:

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
};
```

and

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
};
```

are equivalent.

Having said that, there are specific cases where there is a difference between `typename` and `class`.

The first one is in the case of dependent types. `typename` is used to declare when you are referencing a nested type that depends on another template parameter, such as the `typedef` in this example:

```
template<typename param_t>
class Foo
{
    typedef typename param_t::baz sub_t;
};
```

The second one you actually show in your question, though you might not realize it:

```
template < template < typename, typename > class Container, typename Type >
```

When specifying a **template template**, the `class` keyword MUST be used as above -- it is **not** interchangeable with `typename` in this case *(note: since C++17 both keywords are allowed in this case)*.

You also must use `class` when explicitly instantiating a template:

```
template class Foo<int>;
```

I'm sure that there are other cases that I've missed, but the bottom line is: these two keywords are not equivalent, and these are some common cases where you need to use one or the other.

Comment: That last one is pretty much a special case of the fact that you must use class or struct, not typename, to define a class. Obviously neither of your first two bits of code could be replaced with `template <typename T> typename Foo {};`, because Foo<T> is most definitely a class.

Comment: `std::vector<int>::value_type` is not a dependent type, you don't need `typename` there - you only need it if a type depends on a template parameter, say `template<class T> struct C { typedef typename std::vector<T>::value_type type; };`

Comment: And again, `param_t` is not a dependent type. Dependent types are *names that are dependent on a template parameter*, e.g. `foo<param_t>::some_type`, not template parameters themselves.

Comment: A C++1z proposal [N4051](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html) will allow you to use `typename`, i.e. `template <typename> typename C`.

Comment: As of [`GCC 5`](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html), _G++ now allows typename in a template template parameter_.

Comment: @SteveJessop, template <typename T> typename Foo {};, because Foo<T> is most definitely a class.----ultimately a class is gonna be a type wasn't it, then why we can't typename?

Answer (score 133):

For naming template parameters, `typename` and `class` are equivalent. §14.1.2:

> There is no semantic difference
>   between class and typename in a
>   template-parameter.

`typename` however is possible in another context when using templates - to hint at the compiler that you are referring to a dependent type. §14.6.2:

> A name used in a template declaration
>   or definition and that is dependent on
>   a template-parameter is assumed not to
>   name a type unless the applicable name
>   lookup finds a type name or the name
>   is qualified by the keyword typename.

Example:

```
typename some_template<T>::some_type
```

Without `typename` the compiler can't tell in general whether you are referring to a type or not.

Comment: I understand the rule, but what exactly prevents the compiler from treating some_template<T> as a type internally? Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @batbrat [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/23715) is the elaborate answer on that topic. E.g., `some_template<T>::something * p;` may be a pointer declaration or multiplication.

Comment: Thanks @AlexChe I'll go through the link!

Answer (score 37):

While there is no technical difference, I have seen the two used to denote slightly different things.

For a template that should accept any type as T, including built-ins (such as an array )

```
template<typename T>
class Foo { ... }
```

For a template that will only work where T is a real class.

```
template<class T>
class Foo { ... }
```

But keep in mind that this is purely a style thing some people use. Not mandated by the standard or enforced by compilers

Comment: I don't blame you for mentioning it, but I think this policy is pretty misguided, since programmers end up taking time thinking about something that doesn't matter ("have I used the right one?") to indicate something that doesn't matter ("does there exist a built-in type which implements the interface required of this template parameter?"). If any members of the template parameter are used (`T t; int i = t.toInt();`) then you need a "real class", and your code won't compile if you supply `int` for `T`...

Comment: If you want to limit the use to actual classes, you're better off adding a specialization to throw/cause an error for non-class types. If you want to limit use to particular classes, only specialize for them. In any case, such a stylistic distinction is too subtle to get the message across.

Comment: Since they meant the same thing, please use just one. Otherwise, it's like using inline {, unless it's a Tuesday, and then you using next-line {.

Comment: +1 I do this myself sometimes... `class` implies that you're not just expecting a "value" perhaps supporting some operators, copy or move construction and/or assignment, but specifically need a type supporting some member-access semantics.  The quickest glance at the declaration then sets expectations and discourages e.g. supplying built-in types for `class` parameters when that would certainly be an error.

Comment: I'd like to understand what kinds of real-world situations exist where a template would work for ANY class, but would not work with built-in types. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 12):

1. No difference

   Template type parameter `Container` is itself a template with two type parameters.

Comment: there is a difference in general.

Comment: could those two parameters the container is templated with also be named? in the example they don't have any names. And also - in this example it's written 'class Container' - could there also be written 'typename Container' instead?

Comment: @Mat: yes, the term to search for is *template template parameters/arguments*. E.g.: `template<template<class U> class V> struct C {};`

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference between using `<typename T>` OR `<class T>`; i.e. it is a convention used by C++ programmers. I myself prefer `<typename T>` as it more clearly describes its use; i.e. defining a template with a specific type.

Note: There is one exception where you do have to use `class` (and not `typename`) when declaring a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename> class    T> class C { }; // valid!

template <template <typename> typename T> class C { }; // invalid!
```

In most cases, you will not be defining a nested template definition, so either definition will work -- just be consistent in your use.

Comment: Both definitions are valid as of C++17

Answer (score 7):

This piece of snippet is from c++ primer book. Although I am sure this is wrong.

Each type parameter must be preceded by the keyword class or typename:

```
// error: must precede U with either typename or class
template <typename T, U> T calc(const T&, const U&);
```

These keywords have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably inside a template parameter list. A template parameter list can use both keywords:

```
// ok: no distinction between typename and class in a template parameter list
template <typename T, class U> calc (const T&, const U&);
```

It may seem more intuitive to use the keyword typename rather than class to designate a template type parameter. After all, we can use built-in (nonclass) types as a template type argument. Moreover, typename more clearly indicates that the name that follows is a type name. However, typename was added to C++ after templates were already in widespread use; some programmers continue to use class exclusively