# When can `typename` not be replaced by `class`?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)

I already know in many cases that `class` cannot be replaced by `typename`. I am only talking about the opposite: replacing `typename` by `class`.

Someone pointed out that only `typename` can be used here:

```
template<class param_t> class Foo 
{     
        typedef typename param_t::baz sub_t; 
};
```

But I do not see any problem replacing `typename` with `class` here (in MSVC).
To recap, can I ALWAYS replace typename with class? Please give an example if not.

Comment: In the above case you and some compilers might differ :)

Comment: Already answered here: [C++ difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)

Comment: Could you please clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: "Please give an example if not." You already have an example — for dependent types, you *have* to use `typename`, that's what this keyword was introduced for.

Comment: But I use 'class' instead, it works fine.

Comment: @Rio: It's not fine. You probably use MSVC, which doesn't require `typename` in places where standard does. That you can use `class` is probably an artefact from inheriting `struct x var;` syntax from C. It's a red herring.

Comment: Why this question is being closed as duplicate ? That thread doesn't answer OP's question. I recall there is a corner case where you can only use `typename` and not `class`.

Comment: Thanks Cat Plus Plus, I am using Microsoft C++, which is the only one I have. I feel you are right.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot always replace one with the other.

The two keywords `typename` and `template` are necessary for *name disambiguation* to inform the compiler whether a dependent name is a *value* (no keyword needed), a *type* (needs `typename`), or a *template* (needs `template`):

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
  char bar()
  {
    int x = T::zing;                 // value, no decoration for disambiguation of "T::zing"

    typedef typename T::bongo Type;  // typename, require disambiguation of "T::bongo"

    return T::template zip<Type>(x); // template, require disambiguation of "T::zip"
  }
};
```

Only the keywords `typename` and `template` work in those roles; you cannot replace either by anything else.

Comment: +1, [it's not allowed as soon as you use bar()](http://www.ideone.com/xiJHs) strangely it seems that if `class` instead of `typename` will work, if used inside `Foo` directly (not inside function).

Comment: @iammilind: With `class` in place of `typename`, my GCC says, `error: ‘class ****’ resolves to ‘**** {aka int}’, which is is not a class type`. So you cannot use `class` as a generic disambiguator. However, it seems that you can use it to request a type of class-type explicitly. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use typename for template template arguments:

```
template <
    template <typename> class Container>, // cannot use typename for class
    typename T
  > struct TestMe
{
    Container<T> _data;
    // ... etc.
};
```

This is because only classes can be templated.

Comment: what I am asking is that when I cannot use CLASS. I know I cannot use TYPENAME. Please double check my question.

Comment: @Rio: Please double-check your question to see if you can improve the presentation!