# How can I port msvc++ code with non-dependent names in templates to Linux?

Tags: c++, templates

I can deal with porting platform dependent functions. I have a problem that the compilers I tried on Linux (clang and g++) do not accept the following code, while the msvc++ compiler does:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
protected:
    T Value;
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
    void setValue(const T& inValue){
        Value = inValue;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Derived<int> tmp;
    tmp.setValue(0);
    return 0;
}
```

g++ error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Derived<T>::setValue(const T&)’:
main.cpp:11:3: error: ‘Value’ was not declared in this scope
```

I believe this due to the use of a non-dependent name (`Value`) in the second class. [More information](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/).

The problem is that I have a very large code base, in which this type of code is used very often. I understand that it is wrong when looking at the standard. However it is very convenient not having to write `this->` or `Base<T>::` in front of every use of `Value`. Even writing `using Base<T>::Value;` at the start of the derived class is problematic when you use ~20 members of the base class.

So my question is: are there compilers for Linux that allow this kind of code (with or without extra compiler switches)? Or are there **small** modifications that will allow this code to compile on Linux?

Comment: I'd consider `this->` infront of member access to be a small modification, tbh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to say `this->Value` or `Base<T>::Value`, because `Value` is a dependent name. Alter­natively, add `using Base<T>::Value;` to your derived class definition. There's no way around this.

The Microsoft compiler was simply sub-standard, and it is your misfortune to have coded to a vendor's style and not to the published C++ standard, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You can add using statements to your derived class. That may just complicate your life:

```
template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
    using Base<T>::Value;
public:
    void setValue(const T& inValue){
        Value = inValue;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, there is a compiler for Linux that accepts this code: Intel C++. Tested with version 13.0.0.079. You need to use the `-fpermissive` compiler flag.

I agree with Kerrek SB though; it's best to fix the code. There's no guarantee that Intel C++ will keep the current behavior. There's even no guarantee that Microsoft's compiler will keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Clang supports several [compatibility flags for MSVC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#c_ms).

I believe specifically that `-fdelayed-template-parsing` is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Value in Derived. you can redefine it like the following, so you avoid this-> or Base::

```
using Base<T>::Value
```

just once inside the definiton of Derived and you should be able to use it everywhere

**Edit1:** Ok sorry, I removed the first part about class and typename keywords

Comment: [`class` and `typname` for template type parameters are synonyms.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2023977/500104)