# C++ - Is There Any Point To using <class T> instead of <typename T>

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, typename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ difference of keywords ‘typename’ and ‘class’ in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)

Is there any point/advantage to using:

```
<class T>
```

as opposed to:

```
<typename T>
```

in C++?

Comment: It takes fewer characters, thus reducing the size of your source files :P

Comment: @Mankarse, Wow, talk about being tight on memory.

Comment: Zero reason at all (unless you're some freak that gets paid a bonus for fewer keystrokes in your code).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. The two can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Looks like a fine answer to me.

Comment: @ClementRey why? It's an answer to the question. Not a comment have a look at the faq.

Comment: This is an answer to the questions. I am not sure why Clement Rey -1 because you answered the question. +1 to negate

Comment: So if I am writing a compiler for a language that both integrates and compiles to C++, would you say it is okay to eliminate this?

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain That is totally up to you.

Comment: I just discovered a use case for <typename template<class V> class U> but for the particular case I mentioned, they are interchangeable.