# Generic Classes in C++

Tags: c++

I was reading the topic Generic Classes .I got stuck at one point .Following is the piece of code

```
template <class StackType> class stack
{
    StackType stck[10];
    int tos;
public:
    stack() {tos=0;}
    void push(StackType ob);
    StackType pop();
};
```

My question is that in `template <class StackType> class stack`,
there are two classes made (`StackType` and `stack`)?

I mean how does the compiler treat this as like making stack a nested class of StackType or something else?

Comment: StackType in this case is referring to the kinds of things your stack will contain.  So if you create a stack<int>, you will have a stack of integers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not creating a second class, it is creating one class of type Stack where StackType is being supplanted by a user-given type. A better way to define this is to use typename (§14.1.2), which makes it more clear what is actually going on. For more information on templates, see [C++ Templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

What you are describing is nested classes in templates:

```
template <typename Type>
class Stack
{
public:
    class InnerType
    {
    };
};
```

In this example, InnerType is a class whose strong name is `Stack<Type>::InnerType`, which is a specific class based on the provided type. So if somewhere in code an object is created as follows:

```
auto x = new Stack<int>();
```

then a class of type `Stack<int>::InnerType` will exist. Template classes only exist in the assembly when they are used in code, so if no objects of any variation of `Stack` are implemented, the `InnerType` (of any template type) will not exist.

Also further detail about declaring templates is [discussed here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates).

Comment: ok I got it but instead of stack() {tos=0;} we should have initialized StackType() {tos=0;}.shouldn't we?

Comment: No, StackType is just the data type for the array stck. The field tos is part of the Stack<> class, so your example initializes it correctly.

Comment: Why do you use `new` in your example?

Comment: Well this could definitely be exemplified using a stack variable (such as `Stack<int> a( );`) but it's kind of convention when demonstrating constructors to use heap allocation (new).

Answer (score 4):

There is no second class. `StackType` is the template argument. You can think of it just as you think about the argument to a function with one argument. Unless called and provided its argument, the function cannot do anything. The same with the template class `StackType`, it is the type argument to the template type `stack`. When you provide a type[name] as argument to the template class you **specialize** the template class. All this argument providing and specialization happens at compilation time. For instance, the first time when the compiler meets something like

> stack< int > stackVariable;

or

> typedef stack< int > StackOfInts;

only then does it actually compiles and **instatiates a type** named `stack< int >` - a stack of integers. Until that moment there is no stack of anything.

After instantiation with `int` your class becomes:

```
template<>
class stack< int >
{
  int stck[10];
  int tos;
public:
  stack() {tos=0;}
  void push(int ob);
  int pop();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The `class` inside the `<>` is a different meaning than outside. It's essentially the same thing as `typename`.

Answer (score 2):

So a template is not a class. It is a way for a template to make a class from a user-defined type, e.g., int. So when I say:

```
stack<int>
```

The compiler generates a class `stack < int >` from your class, essentially filling in `StackType` with `int` and compiling that class.

So if I make a:

```
stack<stack<int> >
```

The compiler will generate two classes `stact < int >`  and  `stack < stack < int > >`

Answer (score 1):

Templates create a family of classes - each of them having the same functionality but operate on different types.

In your example it is creating a family of classes. e.g. Stack of class X, Stack of class Y etc.