# Template template parameters, why is class forced?

Tags: c++, templates

The titlen pretty much says all, if I write;

```
                                        vvvvv
template <template <typename, typename> class StdContainer, typename T>
class DerivedContainer: public StdContainer<T, std::allocator<T>>
{ /*...*/ };
```

Why is the class keyword required? That is when typename is allowed, as a replacement in all other template contexts. Disambiguation? Also which part of the standard states this?

Note; I do not derive from std containers, this is just an example.

Comment: Duplicate of [C++ difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)? `template < template < typename, typename > class Container, typename Type >

When specifying a template template, the class keyword MUST be used as above -- it is not interchangeable with typename in this case.`

Comment: Not a dupe, this question aknowledges the difference and asks for rationale.

Comment: @jrok Yeah, the answer doesn't really explain why it's required.

Comment: There are two more recent duplicates to this question: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081405/why-does-not-a-template-template-parameter-allow-typename-after-the-parameter/23965178?noredirect=1#comment47053496_23965178) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965105/why-cant-template-template-parameters-be-introduced-with-typename)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of keyword `class` when declaring template template parameters is mandated by the grammar:

n3337, §14.1 [temp.param]:

> 1 The syntax for template-parameters is:
>
> `template-parameter:`
>
> > `type-parameter`
> >     `parameter-declaration`
>
> `type-parameter:`
>
> > `class ...opt identifier opt`
> >     `class identifier opt = type-id`
> >     `typename ...opt identifier opt`
> >     `typename identifier opt= type-id`
> >     `template < template-parameter-list >` **`class`**  `...opt identifier opt`
> >     `template < template-parameter-list >` **`class`** `identifier opt = id-expression`

I don't know the exact reason for this. When you've got a simple type parameter, the type can be anything from fundamental types to user declared classes, specializations of class templates, etc. When it's a template template parameter, it can only be a name of *class template*. Maybe they wanted to emphasize this difference - or maybe they just didn't bother inserting few more lines in the grammar and adding to confusion. Who knows :)

Comment: Is `template<template<typename, typename> class... Containers>` really allowed?

Comment: @Skeen Apparently it is :)

Comment: Also is `template<template<template<...>>> class` allowed? - Because it seems to be the case if `template-parameter-list` is merely a list of `template-parameter`?

Comment: Yes, `template<template<typename...> class... Containers>` and you can pass the names of all standard lib's containers, if you want :)

Comment: Don't have a quote, but I think Design & Evolution of C++ mentions that there used to be *only* the `class` keyword for all template parameters, which of course later got the `typename` alternative to stress that also non-class types could be template parameters. However, template-template parameters have to be classes, so there the `typename` keyword was not added.

Answer (score 1):

`class` has two meanings: to declare a class (or class template), or to declare a template type parameter.

`typename` can be substituted for the second meaning, but not the first. In a template template parameter, you're declaring a class template, so you must use `class`.

Comment: No, you can't use `struct`.

Comment: @jrok: Really? That seems odd. I'll take your word for it, don't have time to check right now.