# Why can't template template parameters be introduced with "typename"?

Tags: c++

In C++ a template template parameter can only be introduced with the **`class`** keyword. Why is the following illegal :

```
template<template<typename> typename C>
struct A {};
```

I'm looking for the rational behind this restriction, given that a recent [proposal](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4051.html) (featured in isocpp.org headlines) attempts to overcome it.