# Why does not a template template parameter allow 'typename' after the parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, typename

### Template template typename?

When using **template template** syntax as in `template <template <typename> class T>`, it is required to use the keyword `class`, as using `typename` gives an error along the lines of:

> error: template template parameter requires 'class' after the parameter list

Everywhere else the keywords `typename` and `class` *are* interchangeable in the basic case of declaring a template parameter.

You could argue that the requirement when using template template is a hint that you are expected to pass a **class type**, but this is not always the case (especially not after C++11 introduced templated type aliases).

```
template <template <typename> class T> // 'class' keyword required.
struct Foo {
    using type = T<int>;
};

template <typename T>
using type = T (*)();

using func_ptr_t = Foo<type>::type;
```

### What is the reasoning behind this?

- Is there any specific reason as to why `typename` is *not* allowed in template template declarations?
- Does the *C++ standard* say anything about this?

Comment: There's a proposal to allow `typename` right now.

Comment: I am more surprised that it doesn't allow struct.

Comment: [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) now allows typename in a template template parameter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template template parameters, why is class forced?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333990/template-template-parameters-why-is-class-forced)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Short answer**: because the [**Standard says so**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334413/819272).

**Longer answer**: prior to Standardization, C++ templates required the `class` keyword for all template parameters. However, to stress the fact that templates could also be of non-class (i.e. builtin) type, an alternative keyword `typename` was introduced. However, in C++98, template-template parameters could only be of class-type, and this was the reason that the `typename` keyword was not added in that context.

Enter C++11 and its new feature [**template aliases**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1489.pdf), that now also introduced non-class templates, and hence non-class template-template parameters:

```
template<typename T> struct A {};
template<typename T> using B = int;

template<template<typename> class X> struct C;
C<A> ca; // ok
C<B> cb; // ok, not a class template
template<template<typename> typename X> struct D; // error, cannot use typename here
```

The above example was taken from the current C++1z proposal [**N4051**](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4051.html) titled **Allow `typename` in a template template parameter**, and proposes to allow precisely that.

[**Clang 3.5 SVN now supports this**](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) with the `-std=c++1z` flag.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 supports N4051 now too (just checked).

Answer (score 7):

> I'm looking for the rational behind this restriction [...]

Before C++11 was introduced, the only templates you could pass to a template template parameter were **class** templates. 
That's why the use of the keyword `class` was enforced.
Additionally, the keyword `typename` implies that the template parameter is a substitution for an arbitrary *type* and not a *template*, so using `typename` in that context would just blur the line between *the names of types* and (*class*) *templates*.
That's comprehensible.

Nowadays, such arguments can be the names of class templates or **alias templates**, and since those aren't even remotely connected, the enforcement of the keyword `class` is more or less obsolete. The proposal [N4051](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4051.html) opts to change this with C++1Z.

Comment: This answer was given (May 31 '14) before the question was asked (June 6 '14). How is that possible???

Comment: @Walter It was merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965105/why-cant-template-template-parameters-be-introduced-with-typename.

Comment: @T.C. Hmm. Why did the merging mark the first question as duplicate (and hence disabled voting on it) rather than the second? Note that there is an even [older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333990/template-template-parameters-why-is-class-forced?lq=1) of the same content. Shouldn't it be merged too?