# Set private attribute depending on template's typename

Tags: c++, class, templates

**Context:**
We're trying to set up a class template, named Operand, which could take several types as its typename `T`. Those are defined in the following enum:

```
enum eOperandType {
    INT8
    INT16,
    INT32,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
};
```

Those correspond to the types defined in `<cstdint>`, that is, `int8_t, int16_t`, and so on.

The constructor **must** be `Operand(std::string const & value);`.

```
template<class T>
class Operand : public IOperand
{

public:
    Operand(std::string const & value)
    {
        std::stringstream ss(value);

        ss >> _value;
        //_type = ??? ;
    }

[...]

private:
    Operand(void){}

    eOperandType    _type;
    T               _value;
};
```

The interface IOperand is nothing important here, just some prototypes for operator overloads.

**Question:**
What's the best way to set the `_type` attribute? The easy way would be to just write several `if/else if` with `typeid` or something close to that, but I feel like that would be pretty dirty. Furthermore, I just think that using `typeid` inside of a template just means that you're doing something wrong somewhere... right?

Comment: Why not just expose the type `T` as a typedef?

Comment: Why not: `template<typename T> class Operand: public IOPerand` ?

Comment: @TamásSzabó isn't that the same, technically?

cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2024173/4891879

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a helper class to deduce the value of `_type`.

```
template <typename T> struct OperandType;

template <> struct OperandType<int8_t>
{
    static const eOperandType t = INT8;
};

template <> struct OperandType<int16_t>
{
    static const eOperandType t = INT16;
};
```

etc.

and use it as:

```
Operand(std::string const & value) : type_(OperandType<T>::t)
{
   ...
}
```

**PS**

Given that you can deduce the value of `type_` any time you need it, does it make sense to store it as a member variable?

Comment: To answer your PS: the IOperand has getters for those attributes, I just figured I should store them there.

For the actual answer, we figured it was something like this, but weren't sure it was a good thing to do.

Comment: @NathanaelC., it is better to avoid storing redundant data. Storing redundant can be justified only when it is necessary to remove a performance bottleneck. YMMV.

Comment: Didn't think about that, makes perfect sense :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use template overloads. If you specialize the template parameter for each of the types you can set a specific parameter for you can have a specific value in the specialized template. You can then use that value for the `_type` attribute. So if you do something like this

```
template<typename _Ty> struct OperandSelector;

template<> struct OperandSelector<int8_t> {
    static const eOperandType value = INT8;
}
```

and then create another specialization for each of the values you want to use, in your case `INT16`, `INT32`, `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`. To set the value of `_type` you would then assign to it with the value of `OperandSelector<T>::value` like this

```
_type = OperandSelector<T>::value;
```

this approach would allow the selection to be done at compile time and make selecting the value a simple copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

template<class E, E...es>
using enums=std::integer_sequence<E,es...>;

template<class types, class T, class enums>
struct pick;

template<class T0, class...Ts, class T, class E, E e0, E...es>
struct pick< types<T0, Ts...>, T, enums<E,e0,es...>>:
  pick< types<Ts...>, T, enums<E,es...>>
{};

template<class T0, class...Ts, class E, E e0, E...es>
struct pick< types<T0, Ts...>, T0, enums<E,e0,es...>>:
  std::integral_constant<E,e0>
{};
```

then

```
using c_types = types<int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, float, double>;
using e_types = enums<eOperandType, INT8, INT16, INT32, FLOAT, DOUBLE>;
```

and in the class itself:

```
static const eOperandType _type = pick<c_types, T, e_types>::value;
```

this won't work with many 100s of types.

Here I made it `static const`, because it cannot vary, so why let it?