# Matching function for lambda template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I would like to call a method that receives two templates like this code:

```
template<class T>
class Test {
  T t;

public:
  Test(T v):t(v){}

  template<class FUNC, size_t N>
  T Func(FUNC&& fn) {
    T v = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
      v += fn(i);

    return v;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Test<int> t(2);
  auto l = [](size_t i) {return 2*i;};

  int v = t.Func<decltype(l), 3>(l);

  return 0;
}
```

But I got this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Test<int>::Func(main(int, char**)::<lambda(size_t)>&)’
   int v = t.Func<decltype(l), 3>(l);
```

How to macth a method like that?

Comment: `int` is not a class

Comment: Change `&&` to `&`.

Comment: @user4759923 in the context of template specification, [`class` is interchangeable with `typename`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)

Comment: @jaggedSpire Didn't know that, it's very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you change the order of the template arguments, and let the compiler auto-deduce the `FUNC` type.

Like

```
template<size_t N, class FUNC>
T Func(FUNC fn) { ... }
```

And call it as

```
int v = t.Func<3>(l);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should change the order of the template parameters so that only `N` needs to be specified and `FUNC` can just be deduced:

```
template <size_T N, class FUNC>
T Func(FUNC&& fn);

t.Func<3>(l);
```

If you need to explicitly specify `FUNC`, it should be `decltype(l)&` so that by the reference-collapsing rules `FUNC&&` becomes `decltype(l)&` and can bind to the lvalue `l`. If you specify `FUNC` as just `decltype(l)` without the reference, the parameter becomes `decltype(l)&&` which can't bind to an lvalue.

Comment: Otherwise, one can use `T Func(FUNC fn)`.

Comment: Alternatively, `t.Func<decltype(l), 3>((decltype(l)&&)(l));` works.