# Define generic comparison operator

Tags: c++, generics

I came up with the idea to define a generic comparison operator which would work with any type, for the fun of it.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A(int id) : id(id) {}

    private:
        int id;
};

template <class T>
inline bool operator==(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a)) == 0; // implementation is unimportant (can fail because of padding)
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << (A(10) == A(10)) << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << (A(10) == A(15)) << std::endl; // 0
}
```

I think this could be useful to get around the lack of default comparison operator in c++.

Is this a terrible idea? I wonder if doing this could break anything in some circumstances?

Comment: *"implementation is unimportant"* No, it's not. It turns compilation errors into runtime errors. That's bad.

Comment: I meant that it's not the point of the question.

Comment: This is as bad as a `reinterpret_cast` to silence compiler errors. Types that do not define a comparison operator do it for various reasons. You substitute correct, well defined code, for some seldom useful syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Bathsheba Cue someone overloading the unary `operator&` for their type.

Comment: If you have a reference or pointer in your object, you will be   comparing the adresses instead of the values

Comment: And a class with a mutable member is also going to be suspect. Since `const` methods can change the mutable member, but should not make equal objects unequal, it follows that equality can't depend on those `mutable` members.

Comment: Your implementation of `operator==` invokes undefined behaviour if `sizeof(b) < sizeof(a)` though this could be remedied if you use `std::min(sizeof(a), sizeof(b))` instead.

Comment: surely you meant to write `template <typename>` not `template <class>`, right?

Comment: @cat `template <typename T>` and `template <class T>` are exactly the same.

Comment: @MaxV37 Oh, I thought `typename` names any type but `class` is for reference types only, that is actual `class`es

Comment: @cat `typename` and `class` are indeed [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates). That reference type thing is a myth spread by Java coders with a poor understanding of C++ types.

Comment: if I do `string a = "hello world blah blah blah this is a very long string"; string b = a;` then your operator will tell me that `a == b` is false.

Comment: So on top of all headache from C++ you also want the itching of PHP? This is pure masochism.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Doing this is indeed a terrible idea.

If some type does not define an equality operator, it is most likely because you cannot reasonably compare two objects of that type for equality.

Even for the case where the missing equality operator was an oversight by the implementer, any "catch-all" implementation you would come up with is *highly* unlikely to do something sensible.<sup>†</sup>

So to conclude: **Don't do this!** Compile time errors are better than runtime errors; instead of prematurely adding a most certainly broken "solution" hiding the actual problem, add actual solutions as the compile time errors occur.

---

<sup>†</sup>For starters, the solution you came up with fails for types with padding, types with overloaded unary `operator&`, and any type that has some pointer or reference like member; or even types with any member or base of any of the aforementioned categories. So for a *ton* of stuff.

Comment: You probable meant: all structures which do not have standard layout.

Comment: @BЈовић Actually, no. Standard layout types still may have padding, which tends to break that `memcmp` business.

Comment: I meant, all non-standard layout classes will fail this immediately. Padding is additional thing to consider.

Comment: @BЈовић Fair enough. Anyways, the point stands: Breaks for a ton of stuff. :)

Answer (score 25):

Let's take a perfectly normal class, say `String`. It's implemented as you'd think, with a `char*` that points to a `new[]`'ed buffer.

Now compare two of them. Obviously, `String("abc")==String("abc")`. Yet your implementation fails this test, as the two pointers differ.

Equality is defined by the class semantics, not by the bits directly inside the object.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is a terrible idea:
in case of uninitialized pointer:
Here is one **failing** sample (so this code has two different outputs):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A(int id) : id(id) {}

private:
  int id;
  A* a;
};

template <class T> inline bool operator==(const T &a, const T &b) {
  return memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a)) == 0;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << (A(10) == A(10)) << std::endl; // 1
  std::cout << (A(10) == A(15)) << std::endl; // 0
}
```

output:

```
0
0
```

---

and chances for two same values of RAM initial contents for two pointers is highly unlikely, then the other output is:

```
1
0
```

Comment: Actually, your example has undefined behaviour, since the member `a` of `A` is unintialised.   Outputting two zero values is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

As a slight aside, the nicest way I know of writing equality operators for classes with lots of members uses this idea (this code requires C++ 14):

```
#include <tuple>

struct foo
{
    int x    = 1;
    double y = 42.0;
    char z   = 'z';

    auto
    members() const
    {
        return std::tie(x, y, z);
    }
};

inline bool
operator==(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
    return lhs.members() == rhs.members();
}

int
main()
{
    foo f1;
    foo f2;

    return f1 == f2;
}
```

[Code on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%0Astruct+foo%0A%7B%0A++++int+x+%3D+0%3B%0A++++double+y+%3D+0%3B%0A++++char+z+%3D+!'z!'%3B%0A%0A++++auto+members()+const%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+std::tie(x,+y,+z)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ainline+bool+operator%3D%3D(const+foo%26+lhs,+const+foo%26+rhs)%0A%7B%0A++++return+lhs.members()+%3D%3D+rhs.members()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo+f1%3B%0A++++foo+f2%3B%0A%0A++++return+f1+%3D%3D+f2%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.5936863868772,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:31.072980279789455,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)