# C++ Function Template Questions

Tags: c++, templates

I've been using C# so long, I have a couple of questions about function templates in C++.

```
template <typename T>
T max(T x, T y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}
```

1. Why do some examples use `typename` and other examples use `class` in the template parameter declaration? What is the difference?
2. Is there any way to restrict `T` to a particular type, or to a type that derives from a particular type?
3. Is there any way for a class to have two methods with the same name, except one is templated and the other is not?

**UPDATE:**

I appreciate all the answers, but several of them contain examples that I won't compile when I try to apply them to my code.

To clarify question 3, I have the following method:

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery, UINT nOpenType = AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE);
```

I would like to declare a variation of this that uses `CRecordset` as `T`, so that either of the following statements would be valid:

```
auto result = db.ExecuteSqlQuery<CCustomerRecordset>(L"SELECT ...");

auto result = db.ExecuteSqlQuery(L"SELECT ...");
```

Comment: More details about the first question [Difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do some examples use `typename` and other examples use `class` in the template parameter declaration? What is the difference?

Historically,

Only `typename` was allowed for simple template, and `class` should be used for template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename> class C> void foo();
```

with usage such as

```
foo<std::unique_ptr>();
```

There are now (C++17) interchangeable in those contexts.

> Is there any way to restrict `T` to a particular type, or to a type that derives from a particular type?

You might do that with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (which has several syntaxes), and in C++20 with [Concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<some_trait<T>::value> foo();
```

> Is there any way for a class to have two methods with the same name, except one is templated and the other is not?

Yes you might have several overloads that way

```
template <template <class> typename C> void foo();
template <int> void foo();
void foo();
```

or more simply

```
template <typename T> void foo(T); // #1
void foo(int); // #2

// Note that foo<int> (#1 with T = int) is different than foo (#2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get any variations of the last answer to work in my case. My method is `template<typename T> std::unique_ptr<T> ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery, UINT nOpenType = AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE);`, and I'd like a version that uses `CRecordset` as `T` and doesn't require the caller to provide a type argument. I may need to ask a new question here.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9d305987e7b8350)?

Comment: Interesting. That does, in fact, compile when I modified it as follows: `std::unique_ptr<CRecordset> ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery, UINT nOpenType = AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE) { return ExecuteSqlQuery<CRecordset>(pszSqlQuery, nOpenType); }`. However, I'm now getting an unresolved symbol by the linker: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::unique_ptr<class CRecordset,struct std::default_delete<class CRecordset> > __thiscall CDatabaseCommon::ExecuteSqlQuery<class CRecordset>(wchar_t const *,unsigned int)"

Comment: And, in fact, it compiles without the second method if I use your `template <typename T = CRecordset>` syntax. That is far cleaner if it does what I think it does. But I still get the linker errors.

Comment: Looks like the entire function must be declared in the header file.

Comment: @JonathanWood: As mostly every template.

Answer (score 9):

> Why do some examples use `typename` and other examples use `class` in the template parameter declaration? What is the difference?

There is no difference between the two in the template parameter declaration, however they both have additional separate meanings in other contexts. E.g. `typename` is used to mark dependent names as type names and `class` is used to introduce a class declaration.

> Is there any way to restrict T to a particular type, or a type that derives from a particular type?

Yes, one way is to rely on SFINAE to discard instantiations of types satisfying some condition, often facilitated by `std::enable_if`, e.g. (using C++14):

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<SomeBaseClass, T>>
T max(T x, T y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}
```

In the upcoming C++20, there will be support for Concepts, which allow one to write

```
template<std::DerivedFrom<SomeBaseClass> T>
T max(T x, T y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}
```

> Is there any way for a class to have two methods with the same name, except one is templated and the other is not?

Yes, this is possible. In overload resolution, if both candidates would be equally well matching, the non-templated one will be preferred.

Answer (score 6):

1. In this particular context both `class` and `typename` mean exaclty the same, there is no difference. `class` is just a bit shorter :-).
2. Until C++20 we could try and restrict template arguments using sophisticated [template metaprogramming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) in conjunction with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) technique. Basically, it makes template instantiation fail if the argument does not satisfy some condition. While it's very powerfull approach, it has its drawbacks: increased compile times and very long and unclear error messages.

   In C++20 we have a new language feature named [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), which is aimed to do exactly the same in a simple and straightforward way.
3. Yes, a function template can be overloaded with a regular function. If the both match, the regular function will be chosen. Note however that in general [template overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) is quite complicated topic.

Answer (score 5):

1. Old school C++ used 'class', but we now use 'typename'. You can still use class, but typename is recommended.
2. Yes, you can restrict types via specialisation..

```cpp
  template<typename T> T foo(T x); //< no implementation in the generic case

  template<> T foo<float>(T x) { return x; } //< float is allowed
  template<> T foo<double>(T x) { return x; } //< double is allowed
```

And you can handle derived types as well (and there are a few ways to do this)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Cow {};

template<typename T>
struct Moo
{
  // default to false
  template<bool valid = std::is_base_of<Cow, T>::value>
  static void moo()
  {
    std::cout << "No moo for you!" << std::endl;
  }

  // moo if T is a cow
  template<>
  static void moo<true>()
  {
    std::cout << "Mooooo!" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct AberdeenAngus : public Cow {};
struct Sheep {};

int main()
{
    Moo<AberdeenAngus>::moo();
    Moo<Sheep>::moo();
    return 0;
}
```

3. Yes.

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  T thing(T a) { return a; } //< template

  float thing(float a) { return a * 5.0f; } //< function overload
};
```