# Selection Sort - Array vs Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, c++17

I implemented `SelectionSort` algorithm in C++ both using simple arrays and vectors. Tested them with random samples in range [1, 65535]. Here are the results:

```
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Sample Size | Time for impArray | Time for impVector |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|      50     |      9.263 ns     |      32.329 ns     |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|     500     |     471.537 us    |     3039.441 us    |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|     5000    |     117.911 ms    |     1202.402 ms    |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

If this were a time critical application with big sample sizes, implementations would differ a lot. I want to ask the reason of big execution time differences between two implementations?

- Used to compile and measure: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

```
Sorting.h
```

```
#ifndef SORTING_ALGORITHMS_H
#define SORTING_ALGORITHMS_H

#include <utility>
#include <vector>
//#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

namespace etpc
{

    template <class T>
    void sortSelection(T* pArrHead, int i32ArrSize)
    {
        int i32SmallestIndex;
        for(int i=0; i<i32ArrSize-1; i++)
        {
            i32SmallestIndex = i;
            for(int j=i+1; j<i32ArrSize; j++)
            {
                if(pArrHead[j] < pArrHead[i32SmallestIndex])
                    i32SmallestIndex = j;
            }
            if(i32SmallestIndex != i)
            {
                std::swap(pArrHead[i], pArrHead[i32SmallestIndex]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Based on the following answer
    // https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/177919/206877
    // typename vs class
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates
    template <class T>
    void sortSelection(std::vector<T>& vArrHead)
    {
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
        for(it = vArrHead.begin(); it != vArrHead.end(); it++)
        {
            std::iter_swap(it, std::min_element(it, vArrHead.end()));
        }
    }

}
#endif // SORTING_ALGORITHMS_H
```

```
Main.cpp
```

```
#include "Sorting.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template <class T>
void printArr(T* pArrBegin, int i32ArrSize)
{
    for(int i=0; i<i32ArrSize; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pArrBegin[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <class T>
void printVect(std::vector<T>& vArrHead)
{
    for (auto elem : vArrHead)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end;

    static const int i32Size = 1;
    int arr[i32Size] = {0};
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    etpc::sortSelection<int>(arr, i32Size);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference impArray = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ns]" << std::endl;
    //printArr<int>(arr, i32Size);

    std::vector<int> v = {1};
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    etpc::sortSelection<int>(v);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference impVector = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ns]" << std::endl;
    //printVect(v);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that I used the following initializers:

```
static const int i32Size;
i32Size = 50;
i32Size = 500;
i32Size = 5000;
// Use the following link to access the array list
// https://repl.it/repls/BountifulAggravatingPetabyte
```

---

I ran the code with `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp -o main` command with a machine with the following specs:

```
CPU:       Single core Intel Xeon (-MCP-) cache: 46080 KB speed: 2300 MHz (max)
System:    Host: erdem-1 Kernel: 5.0.0-1034-gcp x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 0
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

It seems that implementations are quite equally efficient regarding execution time, not code clutter. The updated results are as follows:

```
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Sample Size | Time for impArray | Time for impVector |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|      50     |      3.154 ns     |      3.499 ns      |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|     500     |     136.928 us    |     240.906 us     |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|     5000    |     14.550 ms     |     14.496 ms      |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I see that you initialize the array and vector with 1 number here. Could you complement your code with how you instantiate them with size 5000?

Comment: @pastaleg I added the array contents.

Comment: But you still have `std::vector<int> v = {1};`.  Please show the real code.  Also, please ensure that optimization was enabled when compiling.

Comment: Did you test your code under release mode?

Comment: If you switch the "vector" implementation to taking a pair of iterators, you can test it with an array, passing `arr, arr + i32Size`. Similarly, you can pass `v.data(), v.size()` to the "array" implementation

Comment: I updated the results, you can check them. I just pasted the array list in place of `{1}` and adjusted static array size. It seems that the first results are due to compilation flags of the website I used.

Comment: What you are learning is that it is hard to get meaningful benchmarks

Comment: @Caleth definetely agreed. Next time, I will look for benchmarking methods (regarding compilation) and then attain the results :)