# Can you replace Typename with an Enum class in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I created an enum class called Colour

```
enum Colour{
    RED, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, WHITE
};
```

Now I am creating a template class called Row. This 'row' class should be templated for a certain colour.

This is what I have written so far in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Colour.h"

template <Colour T> class QwintoRow; 
template <Colour T> ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const QwintoRow<T> &qr);

template <Colour T> 
class QwintoRow{

// stuff
};
```

I guess my question is, does this code make sense? I'm a bit confused with when you would write

```
template <Typename T>
template <Class T>
```

and does it make sense to write template  ?

Thanks

Comment: You meant to enter enum *class* Colour?

Comment: On the last part of the question, [Difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977)

Comment: You may be confused between traditional templates where you pass a *type*, and [non-type template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) where you pass a *value*.  `template <Colour T>` is conceptually the same as `template <int N>`.

Comment: `template <typename T>` and `template <class T>` mean the same thing, namely that `T` is a *type template parameter*. OTOH `template <Colour T>` and `template <int T>` and `template <someOtherType T>` mean a different thing, namely, that `T` is a *non-type template parameter*. Both type and non-type parameters make sense and are usable in their own ways.