# Link error when using a _com_ptr_t (auto-created by #import) only in a template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, import, linker-errors

After [`#import`ing a **.tlb** file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp), I tried to use one of the generated [`_com_ptr_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class) objects in a function template. This works fine if the functions I use are also used outside of a function template. However if it's only used in a function template, I get a link error.

Can anyone explain why this happens? I'm guessing it's to do with template instantiation but I'm not sure how the `#import` mechanism works.
Is it the expected behaviour?

Here's a minimal example which includes all combinations according to the value of `COMPILE_OPTION`.

1. Define only the regular function that uses the object (causing it to be instantiated)
2. Define only the function template (which doesn't cause the used function to be instantiated) - This is the problem case
3. Define both, this shows that if the object is used in a regular function the template option works as expected (and not as in case #2)

Code:

```
#import <mshtml.tlb>

#if COMPILE_OPTION & 1
int foo(MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr elem) {
    return elem->tagName.length();
}
#endif

#if COMPILE_OPTION & 2
template <class T>
int bar(T elem) {
    return elem->tagName.length();
}
#endif

int main() {
#if COMPILE_OPTION & 2
    bar(MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr());
#else
    foo(MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr());
#endif
}
```

Now the following compile successfully:

> cl Source.cpp /DCOMPILE_OPTION=1
> cl Source.cpp /DCOMPILE_OPTION=3

But this one:

> cl Source.cpp /DCOMPILE_OPTION=2

Produces the following (relevant error in bold):

> Source.obj : **error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class _bstr_t __thiscall MSHTML::IHTMLElement::GettagName(void)"** (?GettagName@IHTMLElement@MSHTML@@QAE?AV_bstr_t@@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl bar<class _com_ptr_t<class _com_IIID<struct MSHTML::IHTMLElement,&struct __s_GUID const _GUID_3050f1ff_98b5_11cf_bb82_00aa00bdce0b> > >(class _com_ptr_t<class _com_IIID<struct MSHTML::IHTMLElement,&struct __s_GUID const _GUID_3050f1ff_98b5_11cf_bb82_00aa00bdce0b> >)" (??$bar@V?$_com_ptr_t@V?$_com_IIID@UIHTMLElement@MSHTML@@$1?_GUID_3050f1ff_98b5_11cf_bb82_00aa00bdce0b@@3U__s_GUID@@B@@@@@@YAHV?$_com_ptr_t@V?$_com_IIID@UIHTMLElement@MSHTML@@$1?_GUID_3050f1ff_98b5_11cf_bb82_00aa00bdce0b@@3U__s_GUID@@B@@@@@Z)

> Source.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

**Notes:**

1. A workaround is to use the raw COM methods
2. This is obviously a simplified version, the reason I'm using a template is that I'm using a library that has several types with common functionality that don't share a common base interface.

Comment: Also it’s not a template ‘class’. Usually see template<typename T>

Comment: @DS_London there's no difference between using `class` or `typename`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20semantic%20difference,referring%20to%20a%20dependent%20type.

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks ... did wonder that, just all the examples I see on cppreference.com seem to differentiate.

Comment: @DS_London in templates `class` and `typename` are equivalent. I (and others) tend to use `class` when it's a user-defined class and `typename` when it may also be a primitive type.

Comment: Before C++17, I think you _had_ to use `class` in template template parameters though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is not correct, you could use `typename` back in C++98

Comment: @Motti [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) says "_Unlike type template parameter declaration, template template parameter declaration can only use the keyword `class` and not `typename.` (until C++17)_" [godbolt agrees](https://godbolt.org/z/xsEh31jbv)

Comment: @TedLyngmo my bad, I missed the double `template` in `template template`...

Comment: I replicated the error in MSVC 19 (which also generates a slew of 'forward declaration of enum is nonstandard' errors). The linker error shows that it cannot find the implementation needed for elem->tagName.length(). If I remove all the pre-proc #defines etc, it compiles. If I remove all references to foo(), but put a call to MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr->tagName.length() in main(), it compiles. It seems without a non-templated call, the compiler is not generating the implementation: which somewhat defeats the point of the template in the first place.

Comment: NB. Compiles, but won't run as the default IHTMLElementPtr constructor contains a NULL pointer.

Comment: @DS_London thanks for going to all the effort to reproduce. This was exactly what I was trying to explain by saying "This works fine if the functions I use are also used outside of a function template. However if it's only used in a function template, I get a link error". Do you think I should clarify the question?

Comment: @Motti No, I think your question is fine ... I just didn't read it properly! Clearly the compiler thinks it doesn't need to generate the implementation, but I'm afraid I don't know why.

Comment: @Motti ... I don't know if this is a clue, but it seems like the linker is not seeing the implementations in the mshtml.tli file (which is included by mshtml.tlh). If I use the #import <mshtml.tlb> no_implementation option (which disables the tli file inclusion) and copy the GettagName() implementation into my code, it compiles. That is, I am explicitly giving the compiler the implementation that the linker originally said was missing.

Comment: I found this : https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/832688  .Which talks about add the 'no_function_mapping' tag to the #import directive. If I do that, the code compiles and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, I unearthed this archived
[KB Article](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/832688) which talks about the *#pragma implementation_key* compiler directive, which is used to improve performance when a type library has a lot of methods (over 1000 it seems), which mshtml.tlb does. This directive appears in the generated *mshtml.tlh* and *.tli* files. The article also talks about 'side-effects' which is perhaps what is happening here.

If you add the (undocumented!) 'no_function_mapping' modifier to the #import:

```
#import <mshtml.tlb> no_function_mapping
```

these #pragmas are removed and the code compiles and links.

[EDIT] A bit more explanation / guesswork. It seems MS have introduced the implementation_key pragma to try to improve the performance (somehow) of importing/imported type libraries: in cases where the caller might only use 2 functions out of 10,000's.

This is the section of the generated **mshtml.tlh** header that defines all the individual methods of the type library, all **51,468** of them, surrounded by the *start_map_region* and *stop_map_region* pragmas. The failing method GettagName() is number 190.

```
#pragma start_map_region("your_project_path\Debug\mshtml.tli")
__declspec(implementation_key(1)) void IHTMLStyle::PutfontFamily ( _bstr_t p );
__declspec(implementation_key(2)) _bstr_t IHTMLStyle::GetfontFamily ( );

//And on and on, down to the OP's failing method:
__declspec(implementation_key(190)) _bstr_t IHTMLElement::GettagName ( );

//and on and on, down to:
__declspec(implementation_key(51466)) ISVGElementInstancePtr ISVGUseElement::GetanimatedInstanceRoot ( );
__declspec(implementation_key(51467)) long ISVGElementInstanceList::Getlength ( );
__declspec(implementation_key(51468)) ISVGElementInstancePtr ISVGElementInstanceList::item ( long index );
#pragma stop_map_region
```

And here is the corresponding part in the **mshtml.tli** file which is #include'd by the mshtml.tlh header:

```
#pragma implementation_key(190)
inline _bstr_t MSHTML::IHTMLElement::GettagName ( ) {
    BSTR _result = 0;
    HRESULT _hr = get_tagName(&_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _bstr_t(_result, false);
}
```

The KB article refers to *side effects* of this mapping process. My guess is that when working with this pragmas, the MS compiler can detect explicit calls, eg:

```
MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr elem();
elem->tagName.length();
```

but doesn't recognize the indirect use in the OP's template function.

The *no_function_mapping* qualifier to the #import statement tells the code generator not to add in the *start_map_region*, *stop_map_region*, and *implementation_key* pragmas, and you get 'regular' code, which recognizes the template substitution.

If the OP had chosen a smaller type library for their test, then this 'feature' may not have been apparent, as the *implementation_key* pragma might not have been used.

My minimal tests do not show any size change in the compiled executable, with the *no_function_mapping* modifier.

What the performance improvement might be is unclear. It might be a smaller memory footprint at run-time, as the dual interface doesn't have to keep a track of the dispId's that won't be called. My understanding is a bit vague, but using IDispatch::Invoke() requires determining which dispId will be invoked for a given function name, using some kind of map created after calling IDispatch::GetIdsOfNames(). This map would get pretty large for 50k+ methods, so perhaps the *implementation_key* approach is a way to reduce the size of the map (and hence the lookup time) to contain only those methods that will actually be used?

Comment: I'm not sure how the KB relates to this issue but it does indeed fix the problem, good catch!

Comment: @Motti I added a bit more of an explanation from my investigations ... though you probably know more that you wanted to now!