# Error while creating .tlh and .tli file using #import from MSOUTL.OLB in VC++ program

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, office-interop, outlook-object-model

I want to create **.thl** and **.tli** file of **MSOUTL.OLB** file as I want to use the resulted .thl and .tli file in my C++ project using #include statement. For that I am using below line of code and it throws error as described in below. Any idea why it's happening?

```
#import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSOUTL.OLB" rename("CopyFile", "OlkCopyFile") named_guids
```

**When I compile it. It throws below errors**

```
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6767): error C3646: 'Assistant': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6767): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6777): error C3646: 'Assistance': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6777): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6781): error C3646: 'COMAddIns': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6781): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6783): error C3646: 'PickerDialog': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6783): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6789): error C3646: 'LanguageSettings': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6789): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6797): error C3646: 'AnswerWizard': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6797): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6801): error C3646: 'MsoDebugOptions': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6801): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6805): error C3646: 'DataPrivacyOptions': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6805): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6815): error C3646: 'GetAssistant': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6815): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6815): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6830): error C3646: 'GetCOMAddIns': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6830): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6830): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6833): error C3646: 'GetLanguageSettings': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6833): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6833): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6835): error C3646: 'GetAnswerWizard': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6835): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6835): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6858): error C3646: 'GetAssistance': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6858): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6858): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6860): error C3646: 'GetPickerDialog': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6860): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6860): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6863): error C3646: 'GetMsoDebugOptions': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6863): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6863): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6864): error C3646: 'GetDataPrivacyOptions': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6864): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6864): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(7087): error C3646: 'CreateContactCard': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(7087): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(7088): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(7971): error C3646: 'CommandBars': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(7971): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(8009): error C3646: 'GetCommandBars': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(8009): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(8009): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(18001): error C3646: 'CommandBars': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(18001): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(18057): error C3646: 'GetCommandBars': unknown override specifier
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(18057): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(18057): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(21638): error C2556: 'Outlook::AddressEntryPtr Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from '_bstr_t Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer(void)'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(21536): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(21638): error C2371: 'Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer': redefinition; different basic types
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(21536): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28929): error C2039: 'GetAssistant': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28929): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28929): error C2497: 'AssistantPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28929): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetAssistant'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28939): error C2039: 'GetCOMAddIns': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28939): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28939): error C2497: 'COMAddInsPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28939): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetCOMAddIns'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28942): error C2039: 'GetLanguageSettings': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28942): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28942): error C2497: 'LanguageSettingsPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28942): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetLanguageSettings'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28944): error C2039: 'GetAnswerWizard': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28944): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28944): error C2497: 'AnswerWizardPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28944): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetAnswerWizard'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28956): error C2039: 'GetAssistance': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28956): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28956): error C2497: 'IAssistancePtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28956): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetAssistance'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28958): error C2039: 'GetPickerDialog': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28958): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28958): error C2497: 'PickerDialogPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28958): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetPickerDialog'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28960): error C2039: 'GetMsoDebugOptions': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28960): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28960): error C2497: 'MsoDebugOptionsPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28960): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetMsoDebugOptions'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28961): error C2039: 'GetDataPrivacyOptions': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6756): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_Application'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28961): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28961): error C2497: 'DataPrivacyOptionsPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(28961): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetDataPrivacyOptions'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(29006): error C2039: 'CreateContactCard': is not a member of 'Outlook::_NameSpace'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(6960): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_NameSpace'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(29006): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(29006): error C2497: 'ContactCardPtr': 'implementation_key' can only be applied to function declarations
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(29006): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'CreateContactCard'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(29137): error C2039: 'GetCommandBars': is not a member of 'Outlook::_Inspector'
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(21536): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer'
1>c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(31671): error C2371: 'Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer': redefinition; different basic types
1>  c:\temp\testunicode\testunicode\x64\release\msoutl.tlh(21536): note: see declaration of 'Outlook::_AppointmentItem::GetOrganizer'
```

Any help, how to fix this? Do i need to add any reference or any compiler option?

Comment: Are you using a separate #include for the .tlh file?

Comment: A post from decades ago says that `Assistant` is defined in `MSO9.DLL`.  This could indicate that `MSOUTL.OLB` is not self-contained.

Comment: Update - more recent see 1st answer - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d97bad41-dd38-41cb-a04f-7573236f016d/c-application-using-automation-via-import-directive-no-longer-compiles-with-newer-outlook-version?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, I came across those links too  ... after a bit of trial & error, and some googling: `#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.dll" rename_namespace("Outlook")
#import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSOUTL.OLB" rename_namespace("Outlook") rename ("GetOrganizer", "GetOrganizer1")` did at least compile without error.

Comment: The dependency on MSO.dll appears right at the top of the generated msoutl.tlh: // `Cross-referenced type libraries:
//
//  #import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.DLL"
//`

Comment: @DS_London - This is correct, please answer the question (PS: I wouldn't personally rename the namespaces but instead just add `using namespace Office;` between the two imports)

Answer (score 2):

With a hat-tip to @Simon Mourier, you need to import a dependency first:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.dll" \
    rename("RGB","RGB_mso") rename("DocumentProperties","DocumentProperties_mso") \
    no_function_mapping

using namespace Office;

#import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSOUTL.OLB" \
    rename("GetOrganizer", "GetOrganizer_msoutl") rename("CopyFile","CopyFile_msoutl") rename ("PlaySound","PlaySound_msoutl") \
    no_function_mapping
```

I've renamed all the functions that gave a duplicate warning on my compiler (VS Community 2019) and my versions of the type libraries. I've also added the (undocumented) `no_function_mapping` qualifier, as the function mapping for large type libraries such as these (a somewhat legacy feature for older compilers according to MS) can cause rare issues: [See SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67277912/link-error-when-using-a-com-ptr-t-auto-created-by-import-only-in-a-template/67288488#67288488).