# Why to use the typename or class keyword in c++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, keyword, typename

While defining a template to use custom data types we follow a syntax like:

```
template<class T> 
class Operators{ 
        public:
                T variable1 ;
}
```

Why do we need to use the "class" keyword here, why simply template won't work , also many places "typename" is also used in place of "class: , again  , why is that used  ?

Also when to use "class" keyword and when to use "typename" keyword?

Comment: Please, provide a complete sample code where such syntax appears including all necessary definitions

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2023977/580083)

Comment: there are not type template arguments like integer values.

Comment: As Marek said, you can have a template on non-type, e.g. `template <typename T, std::size_t N> class Array`, with the usage `Array<std::string, 5> myArray;`

Comment: The linked "duplicate" question is another topic.

Comment: @prapin I kind of agree but the problem is that we don't know what is the question about. OP needs to communicate and clarify that. (See the original answer before YSC's edit.)

Comment: The phrase at the top "This question already has answers here:", I attack.
Because the ISO C++ standard has changed the position on the original answer.
Therefore it is not good enough to answer "duplicate question". The original answer does not tell the full picture now.

Answer (score 0):

Using class or typename is the exact same thing, and mostly a matter of preference.

Some people prefere using typename because the type may not be as class, and thus typename seems clearer.

The problem is that the keyword typename has another use, and thus can be very confusion having both in the same line:

```
template<typename Vector, typename Iterator = typename Vector::iterator>
```

In this case, class can help make the difference a little better.

```
template<class Vector, class Iterator = typename Vector::iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

`template class` defines a *template class*.

`template void f()` defines a *template function*.

`template using t` defines a *template alias*.

> Why do we need to use the "class" keyword here, why simply template won't work

Because `template` is not exclusive to classes.

> Also when to use "class" keyword and when to use "typename" keyword?

In this context, they are exact synonyms and a matter of preference. Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I asked the reason why template<class T> has to be written , why can't we just write template<T>?