# Template Template Parameter and Container Value Type

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

**Question Context:**

I am working on a PyTorch CUDA extension that process complex-typed Tensors. I have the following code snippet that is used to launch the CUDA kernel

```
AT_DISPATCH_COMPLEX_TYPES(x.scalar_type(), "my_kernel_function_cuda",
    ([&] {
        my_kernel_function<scalar_t><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(
            x_.data_ptr<scalar_t>(), h_.data_ptr<scalar_t>(), o_.data_ptr<scalar_t>()
        );
    })
);
```

[`AT_DISPATCH_COMPLEX_TYPES`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/8d08b103be936d78d5d4ed90c0547aeccb8ce166/aten/src/ATen/Dispatch.h#L422) pretty much register and dispatch functions for `c10:complex<float>` and `c10:complex<double>`.

A kernel function using template usually goes like this

```
template<typename scalar_t>
__global__ void my_kernel_function (
    const scalar_t* __restrict__ x, const scalar_t* __restrict__ h,
    scalar_t* __restrict__ o
) {
  // Function Body
}
```

---

**Question Problem:**

I need to store these complex values in `__shared__` memory. However, the compiler did not like having `__shared__ scalar_t As[32]` when `scaler_t` is not a basic type (`int`, `float`, `double`, etc.).

Given the compiler ends up generating two functions `scalar_t` -> `c10::complex<float>` and `scalar_t` -> `c10::complex<double>`. I am looking for how to extract the `c10::complex::value_type`, let's call it `ctype` to have in my kernel code something like

```
...
__shared__ ctype As_real[32];
__shared__ ctype As_imag[32];
...
```

---

**My failed attempt**

I tried several variations for my code based on these answers for [Difference of keywords 'typename' and 'class' in templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2024173/2313889) and for [What are some uses of template template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213811/2313889) but without any success. Which shows that I did not fully understood how *template template parameters* work.

Here is one of my attempts to have a single template function code for my kernel.

```
template < template < typename > class ComplexContainer, typename ComplexType>
__global__ void my_kernel_function (
    const ComplexContainer<ComplexType> * __restrict__ x, const ComplexContainer<ComplexType>* __restrict__ h,
    ComplexContainer<ComplexType>* __restrict__ o
) {
    printf("Template of template with complex class\n");
}
```

It does compile, but it is definitely not the solution I need since the compiler can not find it

```
error: no instance of function template "<unnamed>::my_kernel_function" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (c10::complex<float> *, c10::complex<float> *, c10::complex<float> *)

error: no instance of function template "<unnamed>::my_kernel_function" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (c10::complex<double> *, c10::complex<double> *, c10::complex<double> *)
```

---

**Current Alternative:**

As a last resource, I could use template specialization. However, **I would have repeated code** just to change a data type, as show below.

```
template<typename scalar_t>
__global__ void my_kernel_function (
    const scalar_t* __restrict__ x, const scalar_t* __restrict__ h,
    scalar_t* __restrict__ o
) {
  printf("General Case. It should not be invoked\n");
}

using cfloat = c10::complex<float>;
using cdouble = c10::complex<double>;

template<>
__global__ void my_kernel_function (
    const cfloat* __restrict__ x, const cfloat* __restrict__ h,
    cfloat* __restrict__ o
) {
    __shared__ float As_real[32];
    __shared__ float As_imag[32];
    printf("Specialization 1\n");
}

template<>
__global__ void my_kernel_function (
    const cdouble* __restrict__ x, const cdouble* __restrict__ h,
    cdouble* __restrict__ o
) {
    __shared__ double As_real[32];
    __shared__ double As_imag[32];
    printf("Specialization 2\n");
}
```

Comment: As I read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/templates-cpp?view=msvc-170#template_parameters), I wonder if what I am trying to do is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/typename?view=msvc-170#example) maybe what you are looking for. Applied to your case, you can use [`c10::complex<T>::value_type`](https://fossies.org/dox/pytorch-1.11.0/structc10_1_1complex.html#a7ded384f1e0b9ae867aff68100ebf154), and it would be like:

```
template <class complex_t>
__global__ void my_kernel_function (
    const complex_t * __restrict__ x, const complex_t* __restrict__ h,
    complex_t* __restrict__ o
) {
    __shared__ typename complex_t::value_type As_real[32];
    __shared__ typename complex_t::value_type As_imag[32];
    printf("Template of template with complex class: %s --- sizeof: %d\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, sizeof(typename complex_t::value_type));
}
```

---

When `float` is used, the output for each thread is

```
Template of template with complex class: void <unnamed>::my_kernel(const scalar_t *) [with scalar_t = c10::complex<float>] --- sizeof: 4
```

When `double` is used, the output for each thread is

```
...
Template of template with complex class: void <unnamed>::my_kernel(const scalar_t *) [with scalar_t = c10::complex<double>] --- sizeof: 8
...
```