# Use static_assert to check types passed to macro

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, g++, static-assert

I unfortunately have several macros left over from the original version of my library that employed some pretty crazy C. In particular, I have a series of macros that expect certain types to be passed to them. **Is it possible to do something along the lines of:**

```
static_assert(decltype(retval) == bool);
```

**And how? Are there any clever alternatives?**

Yes I'm aware macros are bad. I'm aware C++ is not C, etc.

### Update0

Here is some [related code](http://pastebin.com/vSanw492), and the [source file](http://code.google.com/p/cpfs/source/browse/libcpfs/cpfs.cc). Suggestions are welcome. The original question remains the same.

Comment: Having seen the actual macros, I would _strongly_ suggest to read Modern C++ Design or \[More\] Exceptional C++.

Comment: @MSalters: I can't imagine how C++ can provide implicit alternatives to my entry/exit, but I'll take a look. Also note the writing a FS is very unmeta, my goal is not to create some grand C++ framework.

Comment: You put an object on the stack on entry; any exit from the scope will destroy the object. Thus, on entry the ctor is called, and on exit the dtor is called. The automatic dtor call is especially useful, we know from history that typical programmers will miss the macro on ~5% of all exits from a function.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I found this to be the cleanest, using @[UncleBens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155693/unclebens) suggestion:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(retval), bool>::value, "retval must be bool");
```

Comment: What is the c++03 equivalent?

Comment: @balki: Just upgrade to C++11. C++ is already bad enough, don't make it worse on yourself :)

Comment: When using `std::is_same`, be sure to `#include <type_traits>`.

Comment: This works well for `boolvariable`, but fails for `(boolvariable)` - i.e., parentheses around the variable name cause the variable to be considered a non-boolean type even though it is declared boolean...

Comment: what about const / reference qualifiers?

Comment: C++17 allows `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(retval), bool>);`

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica You can use `std::remove_const`, `std::remove_reference` etc. C++20 also has `std::remove_cvref`.

Comment: @Dino: Yes, I know, I was giving Matt a hint to incorporate that into his answer...

Comment: Documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: Is there any equivalent to this in C, or an alternative work-around using gcc extensions in C to achieve the same result?

Comment: Question posted: ["How to use static assert in C to check the types of parameters passed to a macro"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611626/how-to-use-static-assert-in-c-to-check-the-types-of-parameters-passed-to-a-macro)

Comment: Great answer, @MattJoiner, but it took me a while to figure out how to remove `const` and `volatile` qualifiers, so I've expounded upon your answer in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021981/use-static-assert-to-check-types-passed-to-macro/60769143#60769143.

Answer (score 3):

***Disclaimer: This is a bad answer, there are definitely far better solutions. Just an example :)***

It is bound to be already implemented, but it's trivial to implement yourself;

```
template <class T1, class T2> struct CheckSameType; //no definition
template <class T> struct CheckSameType<T,T>{}; //

template <class T1, class T2>
AssertHasType(T2)
{
   CheckSameType<T1, T2> tmp; //will result in error if T1 is not T2
}
```

To be used like this:

```
AssertHasType<bool>(retval);
```

***Alternative (suggested by GMan):***

```
template <class T1, class T2> struct SameType
{
    enum{value = false};
}
template <class T> struct SameType<T,T>
{
    enum{value = true};
};
```

To be used like

```
static_assert(SameType<decltype(retval), bool>::value);
```

Comment: Not a bad answer/concept at all, though I don't understand `AssertHasType` and the following lines, syntactically. I'd recommend making meta-functions and a static assert utility, though, which provides two re-usable utilities that can combine to make the intended effect, rather than a custom check per condition.

Comment: Or use `is_same` from the `type_traits` header (I hope it is available with VC10).

Answer (score 3):

It appears you need `decltype` because you've got an expression, but want to verify a type. There are already enough ways to do that now (C++03). For instance, to check a bool

```
inline void mustBeBool(bool) { }
template<typename T> inline void mustBeBool(T t) { & (&t); } // Takes address of rvalue (&t)

// Use:
#define DifficultMacro(B) do { mustBeBool(B); foo(B); } while (false)
```

Comment: For boost-level robustness, you'll need an `address_of` template to catch the idiots who have overloaded unary `T::operator&()`

Answer (score 3):

If you DO care about the `const` and `volatile` qualifiers, and want to ensure the `const` and `volatile` parts of the types also exactly match the type you are comparing against, do [like @Matt Joiner says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029310/4561887):

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(my_variable), uint64_t>::value, 
              "type must be `uint64_t`");
```

I you do NOT care about `const`, however, and want to simply ensure the type is a certain type without regard for `const`, do the following instead. Note that `std::remove_const<>::type` is required here:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_const<decltype(my_variable)>::type, uint64_t>::value, 
              "type must be `uint64_t` OR `const uint64_t`");
```

The same goes for `volatile`. In case you don't care about the `volatile` part of the type either, you can ignore it with `std::remove_volatile<>::type`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_volatile<decltype(my_variable)>::type, uint64_t>::value, 
              "type must be `uint64_t` OR `volatile uint64_t`");
```

If you don't care about `const` OR `volatile`, you can remove them both with `std::remove_cv<>::type`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_cv<decltype(my_variable)>::type, uint64_t>::value, 
              "type must be `uint64_t` OR `const uint64_t` OR `volatile uint64_t` OR `volatile const uint64_t`");
```

Note also that as of C++17 you can do:

1. `std::remove_cv_t<decltype(my_variable)>` in place of `std::remove_cv<decltype(my_variable)>::type`, and:
2. `std::is_same_v<some_type, another_type>` in place of `std::is_same<some_type, another_type>::value`.

### References:

1. [Use static_assert to check types passed to macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021981/use-static-assert-to-check-types-passed-to-macro/4029310#4029310)
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same
3. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype
4. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits
5. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv - `std::remove_cv<>`, `std::remove_const<>`, `std::remove_volatile<>`

### Related:

1. [another answer of mine where I use the above `static_assert` tricks] [How to make span of spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449789/how-to-make-span-of-spans/67454463#67454463)
2. [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c/54993033#54993033) [my own answer]
3. [How to use static assert in C to check the types of parameters passed to a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611626/how-to-use-static-assert-in-c-to-check-the-types-of-parameters-passed-to-a-macro) [my own question]
4. [Typechecking macro arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712720/typechecking-macro-arguments-in-c)
5. *****[C++ Limit template type to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848011/c-limit-template-type-to-numbers/44848104#44848104)

Answer (score 1):

Most macros can be replaced with `inline` functions and/or templates. As a case in point, the overly clever argument-size-checking Posix `isnan` macro is a template in C++0x. Oh,bad example, but you get the idea.

The main exceptions to that rule are macros that essentially implement higher level *language* features. For example, smarter exception handling, or covariance, or a parameterized set of declarations.

In some cases the macros that can't be reasonable expressed as `inline` functions or templates, can be replaced with a smarter kind of preprocessing, namely code generation. Then you have a script somewhere that generates the necessary code. For example, it's possible to do options classes in pure C++ with macros and templates, but it's hairy, and as an easier-to-grok and perhaps more maintainable alternative one might use a script that generates the requisite classes, at the cost of extra build steps and dealing with multiple languages.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1. Having seen the code, it becomes obvious that the actual macro's are trivially replaced by a stack-allocated object, dramatically increasing reliability and readability. These macro's are used for function call/return logging.