# How to use static assert in C to check the types of parameters passed to a macro

Tags: c, gcc, types, macros, typechecking

I need to write a C macro that checks to ensure all parameters passed to it are `unsigned` and of the same integer type. Ex: all input params are `uint8_t`, or all `uint16_t`, or all `uint32_t`, or all `uint64_t`.

Here is how this type of checking can be done in C++: [Use static_assert to check types passed to macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021981/use-static-assert-to-check-types-passed-to-macro/4029310#4029310)

Does something similar exist in C, even if only by way of a gcc extension?

Note that static asserts are available in gcc via `_Static_assert`. (See my answer here: [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c/54993033#54993033)).

This fails to work:

```
int a = 1; 
int b = 2;
_Static_assert(__typeof__ a == __typeof__ b, "types don't match");
```

Error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:23:20: error: expected expression before ‘__typeof__’
     _Static_assert(__typeof__ a == __typeof__ b, "types don't match");
```

---

### UPDATE:

Here's precisely how to do what I want in C++ (using a **function template**, **`static_assert`**, and the **`<type_traits>` header file**). I needed to learn this anyway, for comparison purposes, so I just did. Run this code for yourself here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1k-L3HSL.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same()

// Templates: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm

// Goal: test the inputs to a "C macro" (Templated function in this case in C++) to ensure
// they are 1) all the same type, and 2) an unsigned integer type

// 1. This template forces all input parameters to be of the *exact same type*, even 
//    though that type isn't fixed to one type! This is because all 4 inputs to test_func()
//    are of type `T`.
template <typename T>
void test_func(T a, T b, T c, T d)
{
    printf("test_func: a = %u; b = %u; c = %u; d = %u\n", a, b, c, d);

    // 2. The 2nd half of the check: 
    // check to see if the type being passed in is uint8_t OR uint16_t OR uint32_t OR uint64_t!
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), uint8_t>::value ||
                  std::is_same<decltype(a), uint16_t>::value ||
                  std::is_same<decltype(a), uint32_t>::value ||
                  std::is_same<decltype(a), uint64_t>::value,
                  "This code expects the type to be an unsigned integer type\n"
                  "only (uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, or uint64_t).");

    // EVEN BETTER, DO THIS FOR THE static_assert INSTEAD!
    // IE: USE THE TEMPLATE TYPE `T` DIRECTLY!
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, uint8_t>::value ||
                  std::is_same<T, uint16_t>::value ||
                  std::is_same<T, uint32_t>::value ||
                  std::is_same<T, uint64_t>::value,
                  "This code expects the type to be an unsigned integer type\n"
                  "only (uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, or uint64_t).");
}

int main()
{
    printf("Begin\n");

    // TEST A: This FAILS the static assert since they aren't unsigned 
    int i1 = 10;
    test_func(i1, i1, i1, i1); 

    // TEST B: This FAILS to find a valid function from the template since 
    // they aren't all the same type 
    uint8_t i2 = 11;
    uint8_t i3 = 12;
    uint32_t i4 = 13;
    uint32_t i5 = 14;
    test_func(i2, i3, i4, i5);

    // TEST C: this works!
    uint16_t i6 = 15;
    uint16_t i7 = 16;
    uint16_t i8 = 17;
    uint16_t i9 = 18;
    test_func(i6, i7, i8, i9);

    return 0;
}
```

With just TEST A uncommented, you get this failure in the static assert since the inputs aren't unsigned:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void test_func(T, T, T, T) [with T = int]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',46)">main.cpp:46:29</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:32:5: error: static assertion failed: This code expects the type to be an unsigned integer type
only (uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, or uint64_t).
     static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), uint8_t>::value ||
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

with just TEST B uncommented, you get this failure to find a valid function from the template since the template expects all inputs to be the same type `T`:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:54:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘test_func(uint8_t&, uint8_t&, uint32_t&, uint32_t&)’
     test_func(i2, i3, i4, i5);
                             ^
main.cpp:26:6: note: candidate: template void test_func(T, T, T, T)
 void test_func(T a, T b, T c, T d)
      ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:26:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:54:29: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘T’ (‘unsigned char’ and ‘unsigned int’)
     test_func(i2, i3, i4, i5);
                             ^
```

And with just TEST C uncommented, it passes and looks like this!

```
Begin
test_func: a = 15; b = 16; c = 17; d = 18
```

## References:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same/
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same
3. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype
4. [How do I restrict a template class to certain built-in types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976720/how-do-i-restrict-a-template-class-to-certain-built-in-types/16977241)

## Related:

1. [Use static_assert to check types passed to macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021981/use-static-assert-to-check-types-passed-to-macro/60769143#60769143) [my own answer]
2. [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c/54993033#54993033) [my own answer]

Comment: C provides `__typeof__` (GNU C provides `typeof`) that allow you to query for type. See [Referring to a Type with typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but see no way to use it to compare types--only to copy them for instantiation. Ex: `int a; __typeof__ a b;` makes both `a` and `b` of type `int`. However, last I checked, `_Static_assert(__typeof__ a == __typeof__ b, "this failed");` doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: What I was thinking is like a `if (sizeof(__typeof__ a) == sizeof(__typeof__ b))` would distinguish between the `uintX_t` flavors.

Comment: That's true, but you don't even need a `__typeof__` for that though; just do: `if (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b))`, but that doesn't help me distinguish between `signed` and `unsigned` (ex: `int16_t` and `uint16_t`, both of which are 2 bytes), `float` or `double` and `uint32_t` on an 8-bit machine (all 3 of these types are 4-bytes in this case), or `double` and `uint64_t` on a 64-bit machine (both these types are 8 bytes), etc etc. In other words, `sizeof` *appears* to me to be ineffective and lack the necessary granulariy, unless someone knows a special way to use it I don't know.

Comment: That is a quandary, because you can only use `__typeof__` where a `typedef` would be allowed -- which limits the value. I'm not aware of anything else that would get you there -- but I'm not going to rule out someone smarter knowing something that I don't in that department. It's generally not something you run across in C with it being so strongly typed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't believe C provides for `__typeof__`.  I could find no mention of it in the C11 working draft.  I believe that link is merely explaining (in regards to `__typeof__` working for ISO C programs) that compiling with certain flags (such as `-ansi`) will disable the `typeof` keyword, whereas `__typeof__` would not be disabled.  See here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html

Comment: @ChristianGibbons - you are correct. I've searched the standard and it doesn't mention `typeof`. So it won't be fully conforming. And yes, I did miss the alternate keyword implication. Thank you.

Comment: `__typeof__` is a gcc extension, but that's not a problem for me. I frequently rely on gcc extensions which are "non-conforming" to the C or C++ standards. `_Static_assert`, for example, is one of them. Eventually the standard comes around, 10 or 20 years later, and conforms to gcc. :)

Answer (score 4):

If the most important aspect here is that you want it to fail to compile if `a` and `b` are different types, you can make use of C11's `_Generic` along with GCC's `__typeof__` extension to manage this.

A generic example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPE_ASSERT(X,Y) _Generic ((Y), \
    __typeof__(X): _Generic ((X), \
        __typeof__(Y): (void)NULL \
    ) \
)

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1; 
    int b = 2;
    TYPE_ASSERT(a,b);
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Now if we try to compile this code, it will compile fine and everybody is happy.

If we change the type of `b` to `unsigned int`, however, it will fail to compile.

This works because `_Generic` selection uses the type of a controlling expression (`(Y)` in this case) to select a rule to follow and insert code corresponding to the rule.  In this case, we only provided a rule for `__typeof__(X)`, thus if `(X)` is not a compatible type for `(Y)`, there is no suitable rule to select and therefore cannot compile.  To handle arrays, which have a controlling expression that will decay to a pointer, I added another `_Generic` that goes the other way ensuring they must both be compatible with one another rather than accepting one-way compatibility.  And since--as far as I particularly cared--we only wanted to make sure it would fail to compile on a mismatch, rather than execute something particular upon a match, I gave the corresponding rule the task of doing nothing: `(void)NULL`

There is a corner case where this technique stumbles: `_Generic` does not handle Variably Modifiable types since it is handled at compile time.  So if you attempt to do this with a Variable Length Array, it will fail to compile.

To handle your specific use-case for fixed-width unsigned types, we can modify the nested `_Generic` to handle that rather than handling the pecularities of an array:

```
#define TYPE_ASSERT(X,Y) _Generic ((Y), \
    __typeof__(X): _Generic ((Y), \
        uint8_t: (void)NULL, \
        uint16_t: (void)NULL, \
        uint32_t: (void)NULL, \
        uint64_t: (void)NULL \
   ) \
)
```

Example GCC error when passing non-compatible types:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:7:34: error: '_Generic' selector of type 'signed char' is not compatible with any association
    7 |         __typeof__(X): _Generic ((Y), \
      |                                  ^
```

It is worth mentioning that `__typeof__`, being a GCC extension, will not be a solution that is portable to all compilers.  It does seem to work with Clang, though, so that's another major compiler supporting it.

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately it follows the lead of my shoddy example instead of my description. I have a macro where unsigned underflow and overflow is expected, so I need to verify that all inputs are either uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, or uint64_t. They must be one of those and all the same. You've given me a good start though. Also, clang claims to be "gcc compatible", so they make it a point to try to support all gcc extensions and preprocessor directives possible, with identical syntax too. Clang documentation then documents any deviations or nuances & says to reference gcc documentation.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I have updated with another example more specific to your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

### What you want is doable in standard C11, no extensions or GCC required.

We'll build up to the final answer, so all can follow.

---

According to the C11 standard [6.7.10], *static_assert-declaration:* `_Static_assert( constant-expression , string-literal )` is a **Declaration**. Thus if we are going to use a macro, we had best provide a *scope* for a declaration, to keep things tidy. Typically of the usual form:

```
#define MY_AMAZING_MACRO() do {_Static_assert(...some magic...);} while(0)
```

---

Next, so that our _Static_assert within the macro at least repeats via stdio the actual issue if the assert fails, well use familiar stringification setup:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT_H(x)  _Static_assert(x, #x)
#define STATIC_ASSERT(x)    STATIC_ASSERT_H(x)
```

---

Next, we'll use C11's Generic selection feature to declare a macro that returns a constant 1 if the object is of the type we're looking for, and zero otherwise:

```
#define OBJ_IS_OF_TYPE(Type, Obj) _Generic(Obj, Type: 1, default: 0)
```

---

Next we''l make a macro to test if all four of your inputs are of the *same type*:

```
#define ALL_OBJS_ARE_OF_TYPE(Type, Obj_0, Obj_1, Obj_2, Obj_3)  \
    (OBJ_IS_OF_TYPE(Type, Obj_0) &&                             \
     OBJ_IS_OF_TYPE(Type, Obj_1) &&                             \
     OBJ_IS_OF_TYPE(Type, Obj_2) &&                             \
     OBJ_IS_OF_TYPE(Type, Obj_3))
```

---

Next, using the above, well make a macro to test if all four of your inputs are further *one of the four types*:

```
#define IS_ACCEPTABLE(Type_0, Type_1, Type_2, Type_3, Obj_0, Obj_1, Obj_2, Obj_3)   \
    (ALL_OBJS_ARE_OF_TYPE(Type_0, Obj_0, Obj_1, Obj_2, Obj_3) ||                    \
     ALL_OBJS_ARE_OF_TYPE(Type_1, Obj_0, Obj_1, Obj_2, Obj_3) ||                    \
     ALL_OBJS_ARE_OF_TYPE(Type_2, Obj_0, Obj_1, Obj_2, Obj_3) ||                    \
     ALL_OBJS_ARE_OF_TYPE(Type_3, Obj_0, Obj_1, Obj_2, Obj_3))
```

---

### And FINALLY, putting it all together:

```
#define TEST_FUNC(a,b,c,d)                                              \
do                                                                      \
{                                                                       \
    STATIC_ASSERT(IS_ACCEPTABLE(uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t,  \
                                a,       b,        c,        d));       \
} while(0)
```

---

Of course, you could separate the above into more distinct, individual STATIC_ASSERTs, as you wish, if you want more verbose error output if any of the `_Static_assert`s fail.

Answer (score 0):

This was inspired by Gunther's answer, but I wanted to provide a simpler solution without any extra macros.  Here's how you can test the type of one variable:

```
_Static_assert(_Generic(EXPRESSION, TYPE1: 1, TYPE2: 1, default: 0), "wrong type");
```

Here's a concrete example that checks the type of the `errno` variable provided by `errno.h`:

```
_Static_assert(_Generic(errno, int: 1, default: 0), "wrong errno type");
```

I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to test that two variables have the same type.  There might be a simpler way to solve your actual problem, but if I really had to make sure two variables have the same type, and I know the type of the first variable is valid and belongs to a small list, I would do:

```
_Static_assert(_Generic(VAR1, TYPE1: 1, TYPE2: 2) == _Generic(VAR2, TYPE1: 1, TYPE2: 2, default: 0), "wrong VAR2 type");
```

Of course you can do this for any number of variables to ensure they all have the same type.

I might make one macro to simplify all the code above:

```
#define MY_TYPE_ID(v) (_Generic(v, TYPE1: 1, TYPE2: 2, default: 0))
```