# Trick : filling array values using macros (code generation)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, macros

[Are C++ Templates just Macros in disguise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180320/are-c-templates-just-macros-in-disguise)

I was reading the above topic, and suddenly this idea came to my mind: why not try writing some tricky macros which can be used in our real code, (not just only as puzzles which are useless in real life)?

So the first thing came to mind is : filling array values with macros:

```
int f(int &i) { return ++i; }

#define e100     r5(m20)
#define m20      m5,m5,m5,m5
#define m5       r5(e1)
#define e1       f(i)  //avoiding ++i right here, to avoid UB!
#define r5(e)    e,e,e,e,e

int main() {
        int i=0;           //this is used in the macro e1
        int a[] = {e100};  //filling array values with macros!
        int n  = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
        cout << "count = " << n << endl;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
count = 100
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
100
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/nUYrq

Can we further improve this solution in terms of compactness or genericity (possibly both)? Can we get rid of the variable `i` which we need in the macro? Or any other improvement?

I would also like to know if that is valid code both in C++ and C (of course ignoring printing part)?

EDIT:

I realized that the order of calls to `f()` seems still *unspecified*. I'm not sure though, as I think comma in array initialization is *not* probably same as comma operator (in general). But if it is, can we avoid it and what part of the Standard says its *unspecified*?

Comment: @Marcelo: Yeah. I realized that after posting the code. But any improvement, can we avoid it?

Comment: @Nawaz: Sorry, I realised my comment was actually an answer, so I moved it.

Comment: @Downvoters: Why downvote? Is it not a QUESTION, asking improvement/correction?

Comment: @Nawaz - Questions can be bad too. Why are you trying to invent a macro to do what for example `generate()` from <algorithm> can already do?

Comment: @Bo Persson: What is bad in the question? Can't I try something which I don't know yet? Can't I explore the language in a way I never did before? Beside, I don't know `generate()` can be used to fill arrays in the *initialization*. Please show me with an example.

Comment: @Nawaz - Macros are rarely any good. Non-working macros are really bad. It is true that `generate()` is code on a separate line, but has the advantage that it has a defined order.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Thanks for the info. But that isn't my question. I am exploring macro, not template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to delve into Preprocessor programming, I can only recommend the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/) library as a building block, you'll avoid having to rewrite things from scratch.

For example, in order to create your table, I would have used ([ideone](http://ideone.com/J8yHT)):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

#define ORDER(z, n, text) n

int main() {
  int const a[] = { BOOST_PP_ENUM(100, ORDER, ~) };
  std::size_t const n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

  std::cout << "count = " << n << "\n";

  for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i != n ; ++i ) 
    std::cout << a[i] << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

And leave all the cruft to Boost :)

*Note: this enumerates from 0 to 99, not 1 to 100, there are other operations available to perform arithmetic ;)*

**EDIT:** How does this work ?

First, I can only recommend the doc entry for [BOOST_PP_ENUM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum.html)

`BOOST_PP_ENUM` is a macro which takes 3 arguments: `(n, MACRO, data)`

- `n`: an integer
- `MACRO`: a macro accepting 3 arguments: `(z, i, data)`
- `data`: some data, of your convenience, to be passed to `macro`

It will then be replaced by n successive invocations of `MACRO` separated by commas:

```
MACRO(z, 0, data), MACRO(z, 1, data), ... , MACRO(z, n-1, data)
```

It is up to you to do whatever you wish with your `MACRO`.

I am afraid I have never used the `z` argument, it is used internally, and you could in theory use it to speed up the process.

Comment: Ahh, finally, I get to see  one interesting solution. +100000.

Comment: Btw, can you explain this a bit, at least the top level description of each part?

Comment: @Nawaz: I must admit I am guily of using this library, even at work. My personal favs are: `BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAM`, which I have used to generate overloads of various arities for functions (from 0 to 9 usually) because we're still stuck with C++03 at work, and the `BOOST_PP_SEQ` collection, because sequences let you simulate variadic macro with some ease.

Comment: thanks for the description of the parts. btw, doc entry for `BOOST_PP_ENUM` seems to be wrong, I think you didn't intend this link.

Comment: @Nawaz: thanks for the bad link, it seems they changed the website and use i-frames now... hum :/

Answer (score 5):

[P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) has a macro that does exactly what you want

```
#include "p99_map.h"

int Ara[] = { P99_POSS(100) };
```

It has the advantage that it is entirely compile time, no dynamic initialization with functions etc at all.

For you, it probably has the disadvantage that it uses C99 features, in particular macros with variable length arguments.

Comment: +1. Awesome. Can we write such macro ourselves (for C++)? How has it been written?

Comment: @Nawaz, this is by no means straight forward, unfortunately. You'd really have to look into P99 for the details. (Or on my blog for some explanations). Many C++ compilers have variable arguments as an extension, so there it could just work.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not valid code; the behaviour is still undefined. Since there are no sequence points between array-initialisation elements, the calls to f() may occur in any order.

It is possible to generate sequences. Boost.Preprocessor does so, and uses such sequences to emit much more interesting stuff.

Comment: I think it's 'unspecified' now, not 'undefined'.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I lack the time to investigate and thus agree or disagree, but yes, that sounds about right.

Comment: @Marcelo: I think comma in array initialization is not same as comma operator (in general). I maybe wrong. What does the Standard say?

Comment: @Marcelo: Can you give example of `Boost.Preprocessor` which generates sequences. Can it fill array values?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, the comma operator is different to the comma used in array initialisation, but neither usage introduces a sequence point. The comma operator is free to evaluate its arguments in reverse order, as long it "returns" the last argument.

Comment: @Nawaz: Boost.Preprocessor is replete with counting constructs; have a look at the ENUM* family of macros in the [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/) section.

Answer (score 2):

I think still the `template` would provide superior solution which will be definite and less error prone. See the following code; many of things are calculated at compile time only and it **should** generate efficient code.

```
template<int VALUE, int INDEX, int SIZE, bool ALLOW>
struct Assign
{
  static void Element (int *p) 
  {
    Assign<VALUE + 1, INDEX + 1, SIZE, (INDEX < SIZE)>::Element(p);
    p[INDEX] = VALUE;
  }
};
template<int VALUE, int INDEX, int SIZE>
struct Assign<VALUE, INDEX, SIZE, false>
{
  static void Element (int *p) { p[INDEX] = VALUE; }
};

template<int START, int SIZE>
void Initialize (int (&a)[SIZE])
{
  Assign<START, 0, SIZE, true>::Element(a);
}
```

It might be little complex at first glance, but understandable. It can be still made more general. Usage will be as simple as following:

```
int a[100];
Initialize<1>(a);  // '1' is the starting value
```

This can be used for any `int a[N]`. Here is the [output of the code](http://www.ideone.com/XTRL2).

Comment: If you want to use template, then no need to write your own. You can use existing one: http://www.ideone.com/hQG8l .. But then +1 for the attempt. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz, i feel that above template solution would do most of the things at compile time and will give almost the same effect as, `int a[100] = { 1, 2, 3, ..., 99 };` (it will avoid the runtime `i++` kind of operations for larger arrays).

Comment: It does nothing at compile-time as far as array is concerned. There is one function call for each array element.

Comment: @Nawaz, my indication was towards my template solution; it will be done at compile time. However, I can't give guarantee, but I **feel** that compiler should be able to optimize the code and make a line of `p[INDEX] = VALUE;` in actual code which will be equivalent to `int a[100] = { 1, 2, 3, ..., 99 };`. But again, my knowledge is lacking for compilers. :)

Comment: I'm also talking about your template solution. There are exactly 101 function calls. 1 call to `Initialize` function, and other `100` calls to `Assign` function in each instantiated template.

Answer (score 1):

How about some simple code generation.

```
#include <fstream> 

int main() {

    std::ofstream fout("sequence_macros.hpp");

    for(int i=1; i<=100; ++i)
    {
        fout << "#define e" << i << "(a) ";
        fout << "(a+0)";
        for(int j=1; j<i; ++j)
        {
            fout << ",(a+" << j << ")";
        }
        fout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Then putting it to use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sequence_macros.hpp"

int main()
{
   // Create an array with 157 elements, in
   // sequence, starting at 25
   int x[] = {e100(25),e50(25+100),e7(25+100+50)};
   int sz = sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x);
   for(int i=0; i<sz; ++i)
      std::cout << x[i] << '\n';
}
```

Generating the code: http://www.ideone.com/iQjrj

Using the code: http://ideone.com/SQikz

Comment: that will take multiple compilation and running the code; I think OP wants a simpler solution or enhancement.

Comment: +1. I liked the idea which is in fact based on the idea I already implemented. Also, it generates the macros using different program. Can it be merged?

Comment: @Nawaz, for merging these 2; we have to enhance the above program, which will first put the `#define` and then run the actual executable.

Comment: @iammilind: the second link to ideone is merging, but that is not what I meant. I meant, can we write less number of macros doing more and more works, of varying type,  combinatorially, as @Benjamin's solution has too much of macros. They're not much generic.