# How to protect an array definition againt incomplete initialization with non-zero values?

Tags: c++

I have a global array, which is indexed by the values of an enum, which has an element representing number of values. The array must be initialized by a special value, which unfortunately is not a 0.

```
enum {
  A, B, C, COUNT
};

extern const int arr[COUNT];
```

In a .cpp file:

```
const int arr[COUNT] = { -1, -1, -1 };
```

The enum is occasionally changed: new values added, some get removed. The error in my code, which I just fixed was an insufficient number of initialization values, which caused the rest of the array to be initialized with zeroes. I would like to put a safeguard against this kind of error.

The problem is to either guarantee that the `arr` is always completely initialized with the special value (the `-1` in the example) or to break compilation to get the developers attention, so the array can be updated manually.

The recent C++ standards are not available (old ms compilers and some proprietary junk). Templates can be used, to an extent. STL and Boost are strongly prohibited (don't ask), but I wont mind to copy or to reimplement the needed parts.

If it turns out to be impossible, I will have to consider changing the special value to be 0, but I would like to avoid that: the special value (the `-1`) might be a bit too special and encoded implicitly in the rest of the code.

I would like to avoid DSL and code generation: the primary build system is jam on ms windows and it is major PITA to get anything generated there.

Comment: Can you change `arr` from type `const int[COUNT]` to a class type?

Comment: @aschepler No. The values must be known in compile time. No runtime initialization possible, if you wanted to suggest that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978259/programmatically-create-static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c

Comment: @RyanHaining no C++0x here. The answer to that question uses variadic template arguments.

Comment: "STL and Boost are strongly prohibited " - don't solve the small problems like this, tackle the real problems. And that real problem here is not even that STL is prohibited, but the person who decided that.

Comment: @MSalters: in the school, when you had a problem to solve, did you also "improved its constraints" to make the problem be more worthy a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy.

```
enum {
  A, B, C, COUNT
};
extern const int (&arr)[COUNT];

const int (&arr)[COUNT] = (int[]){ -1, -1, -1};

int main() {
   arr[C];
}
```

At first glance this appears to produce overhead, but when you examine it closely, it simply produces *two* names for the same variable as far as the compiler cares.  So no overhead.

Here it is working: http://ideone.com/Zg32zH, and here's what happens in the error case: http://ideone.com/yq5zt3

> prog.cpp:6:27: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const int (&)[3]’ from expression of type ‘const int [2]’

For some compilers you may need to name the temporary

```
const int arr_init[] = { -1, -1, -1};
const int (&arr)[COUNT] = arr_init;
```

## update

I've been informed the first `=(int[]){-1,-1,-1}` version is a compiler extension, and so the second `=arr_init;` version is to be preferred.

Comment: Oh, even if it had the overhead, it would be negligible.

Comment: I think I'm going to accept this as the solution: it is simple, minimal and solves the described problem. Unless someone comes up with a solution to directly initialize the array with the correct amount in the next minutes, that is...

Comment: Pity I can't use it by now: the array has been moved into a structure, where it is to be initialized now: `struct abc { int a, b; int c[COUNT]; };`. So I still have to go with the counting of initializers, but it does not matter for this question anymore.

Comment: @fork0: amusingly, when I saw your first comment, I was able to elide the named temporary :D   But yeah, if it's a member, you'd have to use one of the other answers here.

Comment: BTW, you have to revert the solution to the previous version for the compilers before C++11: `prog.cpp:6: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'const int (&)[3]' from a temporary of type 'int [3]'
`

Answer (score 8):

The best solution I can come up with is to replace `arr[COUNT]` with `arr[]`, and then write a template to assert that `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int) == COUNT`. This won't ensure that it's initalized to `-1`, but it will ensure that you've explicitly initialized the array with the correct number of elements.

C++11's `static_assert` would be even better, or Boost's macro version, but if you don't have either available, you'll have to come up with something on your own.

Comment: A cheap C++98 `static_assert`: `extern int array_size_check[ sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr) == COUNT ? 1 : -1 ];`

Comment: I realize that this is damn unfair, but I made a mistake when stating the question (which I just corrected): the array is referenced externally. It is not static, i.e. local to this compile unit.

Comment: @fork0: That shouldn't make a difference if `COUNT` is the same across all TU.

Comment: @honk: I afraid it does: some of the external code uses sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr) instead of COUNT, IOW it actually depends on the declared size of the array.

Comment: @fork0: You are right, one cannot have an `extern int arr[]` since it is an incomplete type.

Comment: But I wonder if I can put the initializers in a macro and count them using the cheap static_assert above: `#define INITIALIZERS -1, -1, -1, ...\n   struct a{a(){ int tmp[] = INITIALIZERS; array-size-check for tmp }};`

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: while it seems to be impossible to provide the array with the right amount of initializers directly, it is really easy to just test the list of initializers for the right amount:

```
#define INITIALIZERS -1, -1, -1,
struct check {
  check() {
    const char arr[] = {INITIALIZERS};
    typedef char t[sizeof(arr) == COUNT ? 1: -1];
  }
};

const int arr[COUNT] = { INITIALIZERS };
```

Thanks @dauphic for [the idea to use a variable array to count the values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947953/410126).

Answer (score 1):

The [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library might provide something useful, but I doubt whether you will be allowed to use it and it might turn out to be unwieldy to extract from the Boost sources.

This similar question has an answer that looks helpful:
[Trick : filling array values using macros (code generation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080129/trick-filling-array-values-using-macros-code-generation)

Comment: I looked at it actually before asking. I doubt I will be able to find that "something" in the library. Without help, that is

Comment: Updated my answer with a useful link. From StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: I'll have to try that! Can't do that right now, but I certainly will.

Comment: I don't think it can work with compile time constants. Besides, it relies on variadic macro arguments, which is a feature I cannot rely upon to be present in the compilers at my disposition. But I'm going to remember this just for how cool it is, so thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get to an initialization rather than a check is to use a `const` reference to an array, then initialize that array within a global object.  It's still runtime initialization, but idk how you're using it so this may be good enough.

```
#include <cstring>

enum {A, B, C, COUNT};

namespace {
    class ArrayHolder {
        public:
            int array[COUNT];  // internal array
            ArrayHolder () {
                // initialize to all -1s
                memset(this->array, -1, sizeof(this->array));
            }
    };

    const ArrayHolder array_holder; // static global container for the array
}


const int (&arr)[COUNT] = array_holder.array;  // reference to array initailized
                                               // by ArrayHolder constructor
```

You can still use the `sizeof` on it as you would before:

```
for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); ++i) {
        // do something with arr[i]
}
```

---

**Edit**
If the runtime initialization can never be relied on you should check your implementation details in the asm because the values of `arr` even when declared with an initializer may still not be known at until runtime initialization

```
const int arr[1] = {5};

int main() {
    int local_array[arr[0]]; // use arr value as length
    return 0;
}
```

compiling with `g++ -pedantic` gives the warning:

```
 warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘local_array’ [-Wvla]
```

another example where compilation actually fails:

```
const int arr1[1] = {5};
int arr2[arr1[0]];
```

```
error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
```

As for using an array value as a an argument to a global constructor, both constructor calls here are fine:

```
// [...ArrayHolder definition here...]
class IntegerWrapper{
    public:
        int value;
        IntegerWrapper(int i) : value(i) {}
};


const int (&arr)[COUNT] = array_holder.array;

const int arr1[1] = {5};

IntegerWrapper iw1(arr1[0]); //using = {5}
IntegerWrapper iw2(arr[0]);  //using const reference
```

Additionally the order of initalization of global variables across different source files is not defined, you can't guarantee the `arr = {-1, -1, -1};` won't happen until run time.  If the compiler is optimizing out the initialization, then you're relying on *implementation*, not the standard.

The point I really wanna stress here is: `int arr[COUNT] = {-1, -1, -1};` is still runtime initialization unless it can get optimized out.  The only way you could rely on it being constant would be to use C++11's `constexpr` but you don't have that available.

Comment: I don't think it can ever work. The runtime initialization sequence is not defined and cannot be relied upon. What if something else uses the values of `arr` in its global constructor? The constraint "no runtime initialization" is the crucial one.

Comment: I think you're completely wrong regarding the order of initialization. And have you tested your code at all?

Comment: @fork0 Yeah, I tested, and all were compiled using `-pedantic`.  According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271248/c-when-and-how-are-c-global-static-constructors-called I missed the point that initializations from contstant expressions happen before dynamic initialization (constructors) occur.  However, indexing into something initialized by a const expression does not yield a constant expression itself because the contents of the array won't exist until initialization.

Comment: @fork0 I'm not insisting that the reference solution is sufficient, but I am pointing out that if you really can't have any runtime initialization, you already have a problem.  But since you are saying a constant expression initialization works for you, I would like to know the actual constraints of the situation.  I'm very interested in this question.

Comment: the constraints are already stated: the array is referenced from outside. It does not matter in what time during process initialization, but it can be referenced from any initialization routine: global constructor or a function call.

Comment: @fork0 what do you mean by "a function call." as an initialization routine?

Comment: `int func() { return arr[COUNT-1]; } int var = func();`

Comment: But this `int var = arr[COUNT-1];` is just as likely to be present in my situation. Yes, I know it is the same.

Comment: @fork0 If these appear in a different source file than the initialization of `arr` they can fail because the order of initialization is not specified across source file boundaries.  I guess "fail" isn't exactly true.  The outcome isn't well-defined.